# What does the keyword Set actually do in VBA?

Tags: vba, variable-assignment

Hopefully an easy question, but I'd quite like a technical answer to this!

What's the difference between:

```
i = 4
```

and

```
Set i = 4
```

in VBA? I know that the latter will throw an error, but I don't fully understand why.

Comment: Backgrounder here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9924325/17034

Answer (score 106, accepted):

`set` is used to assign a reference to an object. The C equivalent would be

```
 int i;
int* ref_i;

i = 4; // Assigning a value (in VBA: i = 4)
ref_i = &i; //assigning a reference (in VBA: set ref_i = i)
```

Comment: A VB object reference is not quite the same as a C pointer. And there is no equivalent of "&i" in VB.

Comment: No quite the same, no. But close enough for me to understand the concept.

Comment: @Tomalak: You could use VarPtr()

Comment: This is not a good analogy. Take this example (`VBA on the left | C on the right`):
`Dim A, B As Range | Range A, B;`. Going with your analogy, `A = B | A = B;` would be correct (and it would be in C), but `Set A = B | A = &B;` is actually correct in VBA (and it would fail in C).

In VBA, `A = B` and `Set A = B` are BOTH equivalent to C's `A = B;`! The distinction happens somewhere else.

Comment: @NikoO minor nitpick, but your A variable on the left side is of type Variant, not Range.

Answer (score 82):

In your case, it will produce an error. :-)

`Set` assigns an object reference. For all other assignments the (implicit, optional, and little-used) `Let` statement is correct:

```
Set object = New SomeObject
Set object = FunctionReturningAnObjectRef(SomeArgument)

Let i = 0
Let i = FunctionReturningAValue(SomeArgument)

' or, more commonly '

i = 0
i = FunctionReturningAValue(SomeArgument)
```

Answer (score 51):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192490.aspx):

> **Set Keyword:**   In VBA, the Set keyword
>   is necessary to distinguish between
>   assignment of an object and assignment
>   of the default property of the object.
>   Since default properties are not
>   supported in Visual Basic .NET, the
>   Set keyword is not needed and is no
>   longer supported.

Comment: Well found, but a link to the article you found on MSDN would be even better :)

Comment: @Neil - the link is there if you click MSDN in my post.

Comment: When copying off the MSDN, then at least the correct article. This one is referring to VB.NET, not to VBA.

Comment: OP is asking about VBA, and although the info on Set being no longer necessary for use in .NET is useful, it's a off topic and not helpful for people arriving here with the `Object variable or With block variable not set` error from VBA :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the extract from MSDN. All other answers, even the accepted one are missing the point. 'set' is all about the DEFAULT PROPERTY. Just read http://stackoverflow.com/a/9924325/717732

Comment: Just have read the page you mentioned, the author asserts just the opposite:

`If you want to assign the object reference then you have to write:
    Set obj = someObject`

Answer (score 9):

Set is used for setting object references, as opposed to assigning a value.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, Set is used to assign COM objects to variables. By doing a Set I suspect that under the hood it's doing an AddRef() call on the object to manage it's lifetime.

Comment: It's not only used for COM objects, but for all objects. The main reason you use SET is explained by Galwegian.

Answer (score 0):

So when you want to set a value, you don't need "Set"; otherwise, if you are referring to an object, e.g. worksheet/range etc., you need using "Set".

Answer (score -1):

Set is an Keyword and it is used to assign a reference to an Object in VBA.

For E.g.,
*Below example shows how to use of Set in VBA.

Dim WS As Worksheet

Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

WS.Name = "Amit"