# What is the difference between dim and set in vba

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

Pardon me as am a newbie in VBA.

Sometimes I use

```
Dim r as Range
r = Range("A1")
```

Other times I use

```
Set r = Range("A1")
```

What is the difference? And when should I use what?

Comment: I made 2 edits to this which were rolled back... just for discussion... the first was removing "in VBA" from the title since that repeats a tag which I thought was against guidelines and redundant.  The second was removing the [excel] tag since although an Excel example is given, the core question is really not specific to Excel. And this is the dupe target for https://stackoverflow.com/q/349613/3195477 which is a totally general question about this topic. (Maybe the dupe should actually go the other way...)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

There's no reason to use `set` unless referring to an object reference.  It's good practice to only use it in that context.  For all other simple data types, just use an assignment operator.  It's a good idea to `dim` (dimension) ALL variables however:

Examples of simple data types would be `integer`, `long`, `boolean`, `string`.  These are just data types and do not have their own methods and properties.

```
Dim i as Integer
i = 5

Dim myWord as String
myWord = "Whatever I want"
```

An example of an `object` would be a `Range`, a `Worksheet`, or a `Workbook`.  These have their own methods and properties.

```
Dim myRange as Range
Set myRange = Sheet1.Range("A1")
```

If you try to use the last line without `Set`, VB will throw an error. Now that you have an `object` declared you can access its properties and methods.

```
myString = myRange.Value
```

Comment: Can I please know which tutorial or book did you refer to understand this?

Comment: This answer doesn't really explain the "why"

Comment: VBA is very clever, it doesn't require you to tell it what the hell you're doing like a lot of languages. This however adds time. If you are using a whole host of different dimensions on all sorts of different varients then it adds up the time. If you tell VBA what to expect when it sees a variable then it doesn't have to work it out. Also if you tell VBA that a variable is an integer not a string, then it won't take up as much RAM. Although the latter point is probably not as valid in common small VBA projects it's still good coding practise.

Comment: is it okay to use `Set` without `Dim`ing the variable first?

Answer (score 76):

- `Dim` [declares the variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251750(v=office.14).aspx).

  ```
  Dim r As Range
  ```
- `Set` [*sets* the variable to an object reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251642(v=office.14).aspx).

  ```
  Set r = Range("A1")
  ```

---

However, I don't think this is what you're really asking.

> Sometimes I use:
>
> ```
>     Dim r as Range
>     r = Range("A1")
> ```

This will never work. Without `Set` you will receive runtime error [#91 *Object variable or With block variable not set*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264837(v=office.14).aspx). This is because you *must* use `Set` to assign a variables value to an object reference. Then the code above *will* work.

I think the code below illustrates what you're ***really*** asking about. Let's suppose we don't declare a type and let `r` be a `Variant` type instead.

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim r
    debug.print TypeName(r)

    Set r = Range("A1")
    debug.print TypeName(r)

    r = Range("A1")
    debug.print TypeName(r)
End Sub
```

So, let's break down what happens here.

1. `r` is declared as a Variant

   ```
   `Dim r` ' TypeName(r) returns "Empty", which is the value for an uninitialized variant
   ```
2. `r` is set to the `Range` containing cell "A1"

   ```
   Set r = Range("A1") ' TypeName(r) returns "Range"
   ```
3. `r` is set to the *value* of the ***default property*** of `Range("A1")`.

   ```
   r = Range("A1") ' TypeName(r) returns "String"
   ```

In this case, the default property of a Range is `.Value`, so the following two lines of code are equivalent.

```
r = Range("A1")
r = Range("A1").Value
```

For more about default object properties, please see [Chip Pearson's "Default Member of a Class"](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx).

---

As for your `Set` example:

> Other times I use
>
> ```
> Set r = Range("A1")
> ```

This wouldn't work without first declaring that `r` is a `Range` or `Variant` object... using the `Dim` statement - unless you don't have `Option Explicit` enabled, which you should. Always. Otherwise, you're using identifiers that you haven't declared and they are all implicitly declared as  [Variants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251448(v=office.15).aspx).

Comment: @PierreClaverie Yes :) it's including the original references for *Dim* and *Set*

Comment: @Wolf not sure if you're aware, but the VBA language ref is now maintained on github. https://github.com/OfficeDev/VBA-content/blob/master/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/readme.md

Comment: @RubberDuck I was not aware (I'm new to vb*), thanks for adding this note.

Comment: You're welcome @Wolf. I know the VBA & old VB6 docs can be hard to find these days.

Answer (score 12):

Dim: you are defining a variable (here: r is a variable of type Range)

Set: you are setting the property (here: set the value of r to Range("A1") - this is not a type, but a value).

You have to use set with objects, if r were a simple type (e.g. int, string), then you would just write:

```
Dim r As Integer
r=5
```

Answer (score 4):

`Dim` simply declares the value and the type.

`Set` assigns a value to the variable.

Answer (score 2):

If a variable is defined as an object e.g. Dim myfldr As Folder, it is assigned a value by using the keyword, "Set".

Answer (score 1):

`Dim` is short for Dimension and is used in VBA and VB6 to declare local variables.

Set on the other hand, has nothing to do with variable declarations. The `Set` keyword is used to *assign* an object variable to a new object.

Hope that clarifies the difference for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to VBA help on SET statement it sets a reference to an object.so if you change a property the actual object will also changes.

```
Dim newObj as Object
Set var1=Object1(same type as Object)
Set var2=Object1(same type as Object)
Set var3=Object1(same type as Object)
Set var4=Object1(same type as Object)
Var1.property1=NewPropertyValue
```

the other Vars properties also changes,so:

```
Var1.property1=Var2.property1=Var3.property1=Var4.property1=Object1.Property1=NewpropertyValue`
```

actualy all vars are the same!