# How to set range to variable?

Tags: vba, function, excel

I'm trying to save a range from another sheet to a variable and then compare it to a cell.
I have this code:

```
Function collectUtfall(A1 As String, Ax As String)
Dim rng As Variant
Dim sum as Integer

sum = 0

Set rng = Sheets("Utfall").Range("N2").Value <------- This line

If rng = Ax Then
        sum = sum + 10
        Else: sum = 33

End If

collectUtfall = sum
End Function
```

The problem is that it's not acting the way I hoped. I get #Value error, and I have narrowed it down to the line marked in the code. If I remove that line I don't get the error but of course the result is only 0.

I have tried to dim rng As Range also, doesn't work.

What can be the problem?

**EDIT: Original problem solved, but encountered another one.**
If I insted use this code (small changes) I get the same error again. Am I using offset wrong or where is the problem now?

```
Function collectUtfall(A1 As String, Ax As String)
Dim rng As Variant
Dim sum As Integer

sum = 0

rng = Sheets("Utfall").Range("M2:O272").Value

If rng.Offset(0, 1) = Ax Then
    sum = sum + 10
    Else: sum = 33

End If


collectUtfall = sum
End Function
```

Comment: You should honor answer to previous question, marking it as correct and making a new question. `Offset` is a `Range` method. Remove `.Value` and everything should run fine.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Wasn't sure about if I should start a new question or not. Will do next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

I recommend you start learning what `Set` is used for and when.

[Difference between `Dim` and `Set`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872339/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-and-set-in-vba)    - *provided by [Doug Glancy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293078/doug-glancy)*

Also, check out [what datatypes to chose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164754(v=office.10).aspx) for your variables and why. See their limitations and example of usage.

Find out [how to work with Ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa139976(v=office.10).aspx). When to use .Value and when not. When you pointing a variable to a single cell and when to multiple cells.

Learn [how to loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317029/need-help-making-the-vba-excel-code-better/16317480#16317480) over a Range collection.

Read a bit about Code Indentation.

and after that you will be able to write your own:

```
Function collectUtfall(A1 As String, Ax As String)

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sum As Long: sum = 0

    Set rng = Sheets("Utfall").Range("M2:O272")

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng
        If StrComp(cell.Offset(0, 1).Text, Ax, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            sum = sum + 10
        Else
            sum = 33
        End If
    Next

    collectUtfall = sum
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

"Set" is unneeded in `Set rng =`; remove it.

`rng = Sheets("sheet1").Range("N2").Value`

Comment: Wow, that was simple. Thanks! For future reference, when is Set needed?

Comment: You use *Set* when assigning a reference to an *object*.  For example: `Dim c as Range : Set c = Range("A1")`.  In your code, you're assigning rng to a *value*.

Comment: You can find out more on the web. Here's a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872339/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-and-set-in-vba.

Answer (score 0):

You may have conflicting datatypes. If Ax is type string, you should be comparing a string to it. You could define rng as string (dim rng as string), or do cstr:

```
If CStr(Rng) = Ax Then
```