# Subscript out of range - how to assign variable to reference the cell in a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

How do you correct assigna variable to store the reference to the cell ? Last line throws Subscript out of range error

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim variance As Range
Dim risk As Range
Dim time As Range
Dim output As Range

variance = Sheets("ABC").Range("C6")
```

Comment: You have to use the word `Set` to set the range in that variable. `Set variance = Sheets("ABC").Range("C6")`

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872339/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-and-set-in-vba

Comment: @SiddharthRout This also wrong in OP code, but that would be a error 91 "Object variable or With block not set". Actual problem is another.

Comment: Sheet "ABC" exists? Are you running this from a form? Note `Sheets` defaults to `Application.Sheets` which "Returns a Sheets collection that represents all the sheets in the active workbook"

Comment: @LS_dev: I guess that is a typo from the OP. :@Karusmeister: Once you change the above code, if you get the `Subscript out of range error` then check if your sheet name is actually"ABC"

Comment: I guess OP doesn't really have a sheet named "ABC" in place...

Comment: true @ Sam/LS. OP has 2 problems in the above code. `1` There is no sheet with the name "ABC" and `2` In correct way of assigning to range variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set variance = Sheets("ABC").Range("C6")`

+

[What is the difference between dim and set in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872339/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-and-set-in-vba)

+

Subscript out of range means you do not have a sheet named `ABC` or the spelling/casing is different. Make sure it's not an `Abc` or `ABc` etc.