# Object Required Error in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim g1val, g2val As Integer

Set g1val = 0
Set g2val = 0

For i = 3 To 18
    If g1val > Cells(33, i).Value Then
        g1val = g1val
    Else
        g1val = Cells(33, i).Value
    End If
Next i

For j = 32 To 57
    If g2val > Cells(31, j).Value Then
        g2val = g2val
    Else
        g2val = Cells(31, j).Value
    End If
Next j
```

Here on second line i am getting an error saying object required.I have tried to make g1val and g2val as "Double" and tried to give 1 for their values at first.But those didn't work out. Can u help??....

Comment: @mehow: yeah, Second such question that has been asked today :)

Comment: @mehow: Already voted :)

Comment: vote to close ... and delete to follow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to set the value of integer variable we simply assign the value to it.
eg `g1val = 0` where as set keyword is used to assign value to object.

```
Sub test()

Dim g1val, g2val As Integer

  g1val = 0
  g2val = 0

    For i = 3 To 18

     If g1val > Cells(33, i).Value Then
        g1val = g1val
    Else
       g1val = Cells(33, i).Value
     End If

    Next i

    For j = 32 To 57
        If g2val > Cells(31, j).Value Then
           g2val = g2val
        Else
          g2val = Cells(31, j).Value
        End If
    Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks..., it worked. but when i run this code the values of 'g1val' and 'g2val' gets emptied.it doesn't pick up greater value even when there is one.

Comment: @srt Please use the local window to debug the code. This will help you identify the values in the variables. [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: I was using that and that's how i came to know that when codelines related to g1val executes its value become 'empty'...What do u think why is this happening...its not even '0'??!!...

Answer (score 11):

The **Set statement** is only used for object variables (like `Range`, `Cell` or `Worksheet` in Excel), while the simple **equal sign** '=' is used for elementary datatypes like `Integer`. You can find a good explanation for [when to use set here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3884929/2822719).

The other problem is, that your variable `g1val` isn't actually declared as `Integer`, but has the type `Variant`. This is because the **Dim statement** doesn't work the way you would expect it, here (see example below). The variable has to be followed by its type right away, otherwise its type will default to `Variant`. You can only shorten your Dim statement this way:

```
Dim intColumn As Integer, intRow As Integer  'This creates two integers
```

For this reason, you will see the "Empty" instead of the expected "0" in the Watches window.

Try this example to understand the difference:

```
Sub Dimming()

  Dim thisBecomesVariant, thisIsAnInteger As Integer
  Dim integerOne As Integer, integerTwo As Integer

  MsgBox TypeName(thisBecomesVariant)  'Will display "Empty"
  MsgBox TypeName(thisIsAnInteger )  'Will display "Integer"
  MsgBox TypeName(integerOne )  'Will display "Integer"
  MsgBox TypeName(integerTwo )  'Will display "Integer"

  'By assigning an Integer value to a Variant it becomes Integer, too
  thisBecomesVariant = 0
  MsgBox TypeName(thisBecomesVariant)  'Will display "Integer"

End Sub
```

---

Two further notices on your code:

**First remark:**
Instead of writing

```
'If g1val is bigger than the value in the current cell
If g1val > Cells(33, i).Value Then
  g1val = g1val   'Don't change g1val
Else
  g1val = Cells(33, i).Value  'Otherwise set g1val to the cell's value
End If
```

you could simply write

```
'If g1val is smaller or equal than the value in the current cell
If g1val <= Cells(33, i).Value Then
  g1val = Cells(33, i).Value  'Set g1val to the cell's value 
End If
```

Since you don't want to change `g1val` in the other case.

**Second remark:** I encourage you to use [Option Explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2454583/2822719) when programming, to prevent typos in your program. You will then have to declare all variables and the compiler will give you a warning if a variable is unknown.