# Exporting specific cells to MS Access

Tags: excel, ms-access

i had a list of people but it was on pdf i converted it to excel, result was this.

[image]

I want to know if something like this possible

[image]

With my imagination i was hoping there are something that i can do this. Start from first cell -> next cell -> next cell -> add data to NAME_ -> next cell .... -> next row -> add data to STREET NAME .....

I'm sorry if these doesn't make any sense :) i have no experience about this i know sql codes bu i don't think i will be able to get these in order with those codes there are `13056` rows at that excel file `13056/3=4352` people to export

At the end i want to be able to see people from  `"ŞANLIURFA"` with sql codes

```
SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE STATE/PROVINCE = "ŞANLIURFA"
```

**EDIT**

```
Sub fixData()
Dim writeRow As Integer

writeRow = 1
'Iterate through Sheet1 starting at row 9 and ending at 5000
'Skipping every 3 rows
For i = 11 To 5000 Step 3

    'Pick up the streetname from Sheet1 and stick it in Sheet2
    Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value  'Streetname
    Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value  'Building No
    Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value  'Daire No
    Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 4).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value      'Name
    Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 5).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i + 2, 3).Value  'Surname
    Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 6).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value      'Gender
    Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 7).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value      'Baba
    Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 8).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i + 2, 6).Value  'Anne
    Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 9).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 7).Value      'il
    Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 10).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i + 2, 7).Value 'ilce

    '... like 10 more of these

    'Now we've written out one row to sheet2, increment to the next one
    writeRow = writeRow + 1
Next 
End Sub
```

VBA returns a compile error "object required", i checked other questions but couldnt understand.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048601/object-required-error-in-excel-vba) I thought he was missing "Sub" and "End Sub" but that wasnt the case for me since i have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use some VBA to do this. This isn't 100% written and it's making some assumptions (like we are reading data from Sheet1 and writing to Sheet2 and that your data goes up to row 5000).

```
Sub fixData()
    Dim writeRow As Integer

    writeRow = 1
    'Iterate through Sheet1 starting at row 9 and ending at 5000
    'Skipping every 3 rows
    For i = 9 To 5000 Step 3

        'Pick up the streetname from Sheet1 and stick it in Sheet2
        Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value 'Streetname
        Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value 'Building No
        Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value 'Name
        Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 4).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i + 2, 3).Value 'Surname
        '... like 10 more of these

        'Now we've written out one row to sheet2, increment to the next one
        writeRow = writeRow + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, i can continue from that