# VBA Excel - Run-time Error '1004' when trying to assign a value to a Cell

Tags: vba, excel, cells

For the background, see [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21745182). ((I have posted the same code earlier but with different problems.  However, this is a new problem that I have encountered.)

I've gotten rid of a few bugs where I was using a variable.Value, had messed up the syntax for Cells(row, column) and I've just fixed up the `.Find` so that I'm using it correctly now.

I had thought that I was just about there in having this code complete however now I receive a Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or Object-defined error message on this line:

```
Cells(currentRow, dateAddress).Value = billAmount 'Cells(currentRow, "D").Value 
'Populate cell with amount
```

I have tried using `Set`. I have tried creating a variable `billAmount`, assigning it the value from `Cells(currentRow, "D").Value` and then assigning `Cells(currentRow, dateAddress).Value` with it as above.

I have tried just having the one cell equal the other cell `Cells(currentRow, dateAddress).Value = Cells(currentRow, "D").Value` but that doesn't work either.

When in the debugging mode if I hover over `currentRow`, `billAmount` and `dateAddress` they all have the expected values in them. However I just can't seem to get the final cell to populate. Once I've got this solved, I'm sure I'll have to apply it to all the `IF THEN` statements in the last part of my code. But hopefully then it should be complete.

Here is my Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim currentDate As Date
   Dim currentRow As Integer
   Dim repeatuntilDate As Date
   Dim repeatuntilRow As Integer
   Dim dateAddress As String
   Dim dateRange As Range
   Dim lastDate As Range
   Dim billAmount As Integer

   currentRow = 3 'First row of entries
   repeatuntilRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'Last row of entries
   While currentRow < repeatuntilRow 'Loop from first row until last row of entries
    currentDate = Cells(currentRow, "G").Value 'Set Start Date
    repeatuntilDate = Cells(currentRow, "H").Value 'Set End Date
    billAmount = Cells(currentRow, "D").Value
    While currentDate <= repeatuntilDate 'Loop from Start Date until End Date
        With Range("J1:AAI1")
            Set lastDate = .Cells(.Cells.Count) 'Setup for the upcoming Find to begin at the lastDate
        End With
        Set dateRange = Range("J1:AAI1").Find(What:=currentDate, After:=lastDate)
        dateAddress = dateRange.Column 'Obtain column of the found Date
        Cells(currentRow, dateAddress).Value = billAmount 'Cells(currentRow, "D").Value 'Populate cell with amount
        'Increment the currentDate by the chosen frequency
        If Cells(currentRow, "E").Value = "Weekly" Then
            currentDate = DateAdd("ww", 1, currentDate)
        ElseIf Cells(currentRow, "E").Value = "Fortnightly" Then
            currentDate = DateAdd("ww", 2, currentDate)
        ElseIf Cells(currentRow, "E").Value = "Monthly" Then
            currentDate = DateAdd("m", 1, currentDate)
        ElseIf Cells(currentRow, "E").Value = "Quarterly" Then
            currentDate = DateAdd("q", 1, currentDatee)
        ElseIf Cells(currentRow, "E").Value = "6 Monthly" Then
            currentDate = DateAdd("m", 6, currentDate)
        ElseIf Cells(currentRow, "E").Value = "Annually" Then
            currentDate = DateAdd("y", 1, currentDate)
       ' ElseIf Cells(currentRow,"E").Value = "Once off" Then
           ' Exit While
        End If
    Wend
    currentRow = currentRow + 1 'Once row is complete, increment to next row down
   Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not necessary to post the same 500-word disclaimer and long explanation of the same thing in every single post. You can link to the initial question for reference to the background and exclude the repetitive disclaimer entirely. Posts that are vastly too wordy are almost as bad as posts that contain too little information - by the time you wade through all of the unnecessary noise and clutter, it's hard to figure out the question being asked. I've cleaned up some of that to try and make it easier to follow. :-)

Comment: Roger that. I'll make sure to keep that in mind next time. Apologies for the last two lengthy questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior this:

```
Cells(currentRow, dateAddress).Value = billAmount
```

Declare your `dateAddress` variable as an integer because it contains an integer and `Cells(currentRow, dateAddresse)` with `dateAddress` as `String` containing a number will throw `Run-time Error 1004`:

```
Dim dateAddress as Integer
```

Last thing, I suggest you change `dateAddress` to `dateCol` or something so it is clearer for others or even you if you recheck your code a while after you wrote it.

Comment: Actually I was slightly sneaky there which you might not have seen. The line above that reads `dateAddress = dateRange.Column` so when calling it in the `Cells()` it is actually already the current value of the column. I'm afraid there is something else fishy going on.

Comment: @Bzmek; sorry, my bad.  Remembered your code from yesterday ;)  But, since `dateAddress` now contains an integer (because `.Column` returns a clolumn number) you should declare it as so (`Dim dateAddress as Integer`)  Then try it.

Comment: Ah your a legend simpLE MAn! That fixed it. Yeah thought you might have been still thinking of yesterday's code :) Fixed that up now and it works great. It looks like I have one final error in that the `currentDate` is thrown out of control when the start date is before the first possible date in my range. I'm thinking I'll just make a check loop to make sure this is dealt with and all should be fine. Thank you!