# Assign Range to Class Property

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Class InsertInfo with the Properrty

```
Private myPPTRange As Range

Public Property Get PPTRange() As Range
PPTRange = myPPTRange
End Property
Public Property Set PPTRange(ByVal value As Range)
myPPTRange = value
End Property
```

Now I want to assign a range to it with

```
Sub test()

Dim objInfo as New InsertInfo

    Set objInfo.PPTRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab").Cells(1,2)

End Sub
```

Usually assigning a cell to a range works fine in the code but in the situation above I always get the error:

```
"Objectvariable or with-blockvariable not set"
```

So to me it looks like it has something to do with the class property but I just cannot see what the problem is. Anyone who can help me with it?

EDIT:

```
Dim rngTemp as Range
Set rngTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab").Cells(1,2)
```

works fine btw. So it really looks like I have to adjust my class property. I already tried a ByRef instead of a ByVal but I still get the Error Message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Set` while assigning to a range object.

`myPPTRange` is a range. So in your class module, change the line `myPPTRange = value` to `Set myPPTRange = value`

Comment: Do both his Get and Set Properties need to be changed to "Set PPTRange"?

Comment: @user117294: Yes. Whenever you are working with objects, you need to use SET in such scenarios. You may want to see [What is the difference between dim and set in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872339/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-and-set-in-vba)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using SET inside your property, you may also need to define your object in two lines instead of single line definition syntax.

```
Dim objInfo as InsertInfo
set objInfo = New InsertInfo
```