# Trouble with vba error 91 when using With, Range and .Find

Tags: vba, excel

i would like to find the address of the cell containing the value "USD" in below mentioned code. though, the system throws me an error 91 saying that an object variable has not been set. i found some info online on error 91 but i still don't get where and how to set the right object. help is appreciated.

thanks

```
Sub searchAdress()
 Dim searchAdress As Range
 With Workbooks("Umrechnungskurse1.xlsm").Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A2:S2")
    searchAdress = .Find("USD", LookIn:=xlValues)
 End With
 MsgBox searchAdress
End Sub
```

Comment: on which line do you get the error?

Comment: `.Find` inherits many parameters from the last time it was used. Do you want `XlPart` or `xlWhole`? There are several others but that is likely the most important.

Comment: You are missing `Set` before `searchAdress`

Comment: See the first example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872339/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-and-set-in-vba

Comment: Offtopic: Also since you are using `.Find`, you may find [this](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) topic interesting

Comment: thanks guys, it was the missing set command. reading your linked articles now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that your line:
`searchAdress = .Find("USD", LookIn:=xlValues)`

Should be :
`Set searchAdress = .Find("USD", LookIn:=xlValues)`
The `Set` command is required for object variables.

Your next problem is that your `MsgBox` will not work.  Change the line to:
`MsgBox searchAdress.Address`