# Setting a Range of Cells Back to Itself

Tags: vba, excel

I was just curious if there was an easy way to almost do a cut in page with vba code.  Let me explain a bit.

Lets Say we have a NamedRange Called `LookUpTableData$A1:$D10`
each cell in the range has different data, and by data i mean contents, not datatype.

So lets say i retrieve the range in VBA like this.

```
CompleteModifiedRange = Range("LookUpTableData")
'Now I make some changes to the data
CompleteModifiedRange.Cells(1,1).Value = Blah
CompleteModifiedRange.Cells(2,1).Value = Blah2
```

So the real question is, How can i sort of paste the entire range back in place without having to loop through all the cells and set them? Kind of like this.

```
Set Range("LookUpTableData").Range = CompleteModifiedRange
```

Is there such a way?

Comment: Amusingly, your first line of code shows how to do it, just in reverse (that is, [without `Set`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3872339/11683)).

Comment: [**Use `Option Explicit`**](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3992/vba-option-keyword/13935/option-explicit#t=201609081401041799404). If `CompleteModifiedRange` was properly declared with a `Range` type, things would have been much less confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've basically almost answered your own question. Because you didn't use `Set`, your `CompleteModifiedRange` variable actually contains an array, and therefore you wouldn't use `Cells` with it:

```
Dim CompleteModifiedRange As Variant
CompleteModifiedRange = Range("LookUpTableData").Value
'Now I make some changes to the data
CompleteModifiedRange(1,1).Value = Blah
CompleteModifiedRange(2,1).Value = Blah2
Range("LookUpTableData").Value = CompleteModifiedRange
```

Comment: Thanks i tried assigning it directly but wasn't working.  This works.  Thanks