# Excel VBA macro type mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

I found out that an office at my work spent weeks manually going through an Excel spreadsheet containing a database with >500,000 rows looking for duplicate rows matching certain criteria. The duplicates could not simply be erased before being researched, as a single mistake could have potentially lost hundreds of thousands of dollars in lost production. I decided simply flagging them and referencing the originating row would be the best answer in this case. So I decided to look into macros to see how much time *could* have been saved by using a simple macro instead. I am using this as a programming learning experience, so please no "here's a =function()" answers.

I've written a macro and changed it several times to no avail (most current is below). I wanted to use String variables because there's no telling what has been entered into the cells that will be checked. Here's what I've tried, failed, and learned(?) from this site:

Initially, I tried declaring a variable, and attaching a value from a cell directly to it. e.g. `Dim myString As String    Set myString = Cells(x, x).Value` However, I kept getting object errors. Thanks to [Michael's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/323560/michael) response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872339/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-and-set-in-vba), I learned that you have to use the `Range` variable to use `Set`.

My next issue has been getting a "type mismatch" error. I'm trying to assign and compare a stored variable against another stored variable, and I'm sure this is causing the issue. I initially tried `Dim myRange As Range, myString As String    Set myRange = Cells(x, x).Value    myString = myRange`. This obviously didn't work, so I tried using the `CStr()` "change to string" function to convert the Range variable to the String variable I want. And that's where I'm stuck.

```
Sub Duplicate()

'Declare the variables
Dim NSNrange, PNrange, KitIDrange As Range
Dim NSN, PN, KitID As String
Dim NSNCheck, PNCheck, KitIDCheck As String
Dim i, j, printColumn, rowCount As Integer

'Set which column we want to print duplicates on, and count the number of rows used
rowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
printColumn = 9

'Lets get started!

'Clear the duplicate list column for a fresh start
Columns(printColumn).EntireColumn.Delete

'Start on line 2, and grab the cell values for the NSN, Part number and kit ID.
For i = 2 To rowCount

   Set NSNrange = Cells(i, 5).Value
   Set PNrange = Cells(i, 7).Value
   Set KitIDrange = Cells(i, 2).Value

   'Change whatever is contained in those cells into a string and store them into their respective containers
   NSN = CStr(NSNrange)
   PN = CStr(PNrange)
   KitID = CStr(KitIDrange)


      'Now let's look through the rest of the sheet and find any others that match the 3 variables that we stored above
      For j = 2 To rowCount

      'To avoid needless checks, we'll check to see if it's already had a duplicate found. If so, we'll just skip to the next row
      If Cells(j, printColumn).Value = "" Then

      'If the print column is blank, we'll grab the 3 values from the current row to compare against the above variables
      Set NSNrange = Cells(j, 5).Value
      Set PNrange = Cells(j, 7).Value
      Set KitIDrange = Cells(j, 2).Value

      'Now we store the contents into their very own container
      NSNCheck = CStr(NSNrange)
      PNCheck = CStr(PNrange)
      KitIDCheck = CStr(KitIDrange)

         'Check the initial row with the current row to see if the contents match. If so, print which row it is duplicated on.
         If NSN = NSNCheck And PN = PNCheck And KitID = KitIDCheck Then Cells(j, printColumn).Value = "Duplicated on row " & i


        End If

        Next j


   Next i

MsgBox "Search Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `Dim myRange As Range, myString As String    Set myRange = Cells(x, x)    myString = myRange.Value` ? **Note the shift of the `.Value` property.**

Comment: Which line is returning `Type Mismatch`

Comment: Funny how some acronyms mean something. This is data cleansing a stores database or finding out if someone has been issued with too much kit? GMalc provided an answer that uses `RemoveDuplicates` but I suspect that you don't want to remove them, but find them and highlight them. If this is the case, can you please add that into your question so other answerer's can understand the context.

Comment: ADJ, You are correct. I changed my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asked for comments in relation to type errors. There are a number of place where confusion could arise

1)  Every line where you do multiple declarations on the same line like this:

```
Dim NSNrange, PNrange, KitIDrange As Range
```

Only the last variable is explicitly type declared (in this case as a `Range`). The others are implicit `Variant`.  So, I have gone through and put on separate lines and declared them as I believe you may have meant them to be.

2) Using `Activesheet` and, in other places, just `Cells` or `Range`, which implicitly references the `Activesheet`, means if you have changed sheets by then you may longer be referring to the sheet you intended. So whilst I have kept `Activesheet` in, and used an overarching `With Activesheet` statement that then allows me to say `.Cells` or `.Range` etc, you should change this to using explicit sheet names.

3) Where ever you use the `Set` keyword the expectation is your are working with an object (e.g. a `Range`). Going by your naming convention I am going to say that you mean

```
Set NSNrange = Cells(i, 5)
```

when you say

```
Set NSNrange = Cells(i, 5).Value
```

Which sets a range to another range rather than a cell value.

4) I have changed your Integers to Longs. You are working with rows which can go beyond what `Integer` type can handle so you risked overflow. `Long` is safer.

5) Rather than doing a conversion on the `Range`  as follows

```
NSN = CStr(NSNrange)
```

Where the default property of the range, `.Value`, will be taken, as you want a string you can drop the `CStr` conversion and just take the `.Text` property which will give you the string you want.

6) Rather than the empty string literal `""` comparison, I have used `vbNullString` which is faster to assign and to check.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Duplicate()

    Dim NSNrange As Range
    Dim PNrange As Range
    Dim KitIDrange As Range
    Dim NSN As String
    Dim PN As String
    Dim KitID As String
    Dim NSNCheck As String
    Dim PNCheck As String
    Dim KitIDCheck As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim printColumn As Long
    Dim rowCount As Long

    With ActiveSheet

        rowCount = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

        printColumn = 9

        .Columns(printColumn).EntireColumn.Delete

        For i = 2 To rowCount

            Set NSNrange = .Cells(i, 5)
            Set PNrange = .Cells(i, 7)
            Set KitIDrange = .Cells(i, 2)

            NSN = NSNrange.Text
            PN = PNrange.Text
            KitID = KitIDrange.Text

            For j = 2 To rowCount

                If .Cells(j, printColumn).Value = vbNullString Then

                    Set NSNrange = .Cells(j, 5)
                    Set PNrange = .Cells(j, 7)
                    Set KitIDrange = .Cells(j, 2)

                    NSNCheck = NSNrange.Text
                    PNCheck = PNrange.Text
                    KitIDCheck = KitIDrange.Text

                    If NSN = NSNCheck And PN = PNCheck And KitID = KitIDCheck Then
                        .Cells(j, printColumn).Value = "Duplicated on row " & i
                    End If

                End If

            Next j

        Next i

    End With

    MsgBox "Search Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: This is fantastic. The only other issue I found to make this code work (simple mistake on my part) was to change `For j = 2 To rowCount` to `For j =  i + 1 To rowCount` Otherwise it'll show every line as a duplicate since it will compare every line against itself. Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

So it's correct that you assign **objects** with `set` (not just  `range`). A `cell` is an object and can be assigned to a `range` variable. But when you use **methods** and **properties** of objects, in this case `.Value`, it does not mean that the return value is a `range` object.

So if you need to know what all propertys and methods to, i highly recommend the [microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/office-vba-reference).

So when you use `.Value`, you get back a variant (depending on the type of the value). In your use-case you can just assign it to a `string`, i.e `Dim str as string: str = Cells(1,1).Value`. If you just want the `cell`as an object that you can reference: `Dim cell as Range: Set cell = Cells(1,1)`. Now can can adress all propertys and methods for example: `cell.Value` instead of `Cells(1,1).Value`.

Just a few other things that are useful to know. In VBA not like in VB.Net, that you better not mix up, if you `Dim var1, var2 as String` **only** `var2` is a `string`, `var1` is a `variant`. So its required to specify the type for each variable, `Dim var1 as String, var2 as String`.

Another thing that you might want to change is assigning `Cells, Range` to a specific `Worksheet`. Depending on which module your code is in, it can happen that you code runs on the wrong worksheet. (Also it minimizes errors when other people adjust/run the code), but mainly you just have to change one variable, if you want to refer to another `Worksheet`. It can be done with using `Worksheet-Object`.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim str as String
Set ws = Worksheets(1)
'Now adress methods and properties with ws
str = ws.Cells(1,1).Value
```

Also note here the **object** is `Worksheet` without an `s`. `Worksheets` is the collection of the `Worksheet` of the current `Workbook`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the RemoveDuplicates method.

```
'Remove duplicates based on the data in columns; 2 "Kit", 5 "NSN", and 7 "PN".
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2, 5, 7), Header:=xlYes
```