# Why a this variable declared as a Range is declared equal to null?

Tags: excel, vba

Hi everyone I'm just curious about why this code works and the next one doesn't here it goes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As String
cell = Sheets("IntQ").Range("A5").Value
 If cell = "" Then
  cell = "This should work"
  Sheets("IntQ").Range("A5").Value = cell
 End If
End Sub
```

Here goes the code that doesn't work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range
cell = Sheets("IntQ").Range("A5")
 If cell.Value = "" Then
  cell.Value = "Elige la marca del producto"
 End If
End Sub
```

The prompt says that the cell variable value is null

Comment: I'm trying that the cell A5 shows a value when it is empty

Comment: Are you using `Option explicit`? Try it like this instead: `Set cell = Sheets("IntQ").Range("A5")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between dim and set in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872339/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-and-set-in-vba)

Comment: And keep in mind that an empty string is not the same thing as `null`.