# invalid use of property when dealing with list objects

Tags: excel, vba, listobject, excel-tables

Im getting an invalid use of property error on the line where I try to assign the formatted table name to tables. I'm assuming this is a syntactical issue. However, I'm not sure what I want to do is possible without more code or different code. I want to grab the tablename of the activesheet so that in the next line it can be added in the range to create formatted table syntax(i.e. MyTable[EntityID])

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wbkCurBook As Workbook
Dim searchValue As String
Dim searchSheet As String
Dim tableMatch As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim combined As String
Dim x As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim tables As ListObject

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

'highlight all entityIDs with missing definitions
    For x = 3 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(x).Activate
        ws = ActiveSheet
        tables = Sheets(x).ListObjects
                For Each cell In Sheets(x).Range(tables & "[EntityID]")
                    searchValue = cell.Value
                    searchSheet = Sheets(x).Name
                    combined = searchSheet & " " & searchValue
                    
                    With wbkCurBook.Sheets("Data Dictionary").Range("Dictionary[CombinedName]")
                            Set tableMatch = .Find(What:=combined, _
                                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                            MatchCase:=False)

                        If tableMatch Is Nothing Then
                                cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                        End If
                    End With
                Next cell
    Next x
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
 End Sub
```

Comment: Which code line shows the error?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have declared `Dim tables As ListObject`, you have to use [SET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872339/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-and-set-in-vba). Also you will have to tell which table you want to work with.

Change

```
tables = Sheets(x).ListObjects
```

to

```
Set tables = Sheets(x).ListObjects(1)
```

And then use it like `tables.Name`

For example

```
Dim tables As ListObject

Set tables = Sheets(1).ListObjects(1)

Debug.Print tables.Name & "[EntityID]"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Highlight Missing

- The code should be copied into a standard module e.g. `Module1`, but you can copy it to the `ThisWorkbook` module. Then, in your `Open` event procedure (in the `ThisWorkbook module`), just use the line `HighlightMissingDefinitions`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HighlightMissingDefinitions()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Data Dictionary")
    Dim stbl As ListObject: Set stbl = sws.ListObjects("Dictionary")
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = stbl.ListColumns("CombinedStringName").DataBodyRange
    Dim sCell As Range
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim dtbl As ListObject
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim d As Long
    Dim dWorksheetName As String
    Dim dSearchString As String
    Dim dCombinedString As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Highlight
    For d = 3 To wb.Worksheets.Count
        Set drg = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set dws = wb.Worksheets(d)
        Set dtbl = dws.ListObjects(1)
        Set drg = dtbl.ListColumns("EntityID").DataBodyRange
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not drg Is Nothing Then
            drg.Interior.Color = xlNone
            For Each dCell In drg.Cells
                dSearchString = CStr(dCell.Value)
                dWorksheetName = dws.Name
                dCombinedString = dWorksheetName & " " & dSearchString
                ' You could just do:
                'dCombinedString = dws.Name & " " & CStr(dCell.Value)
                ' No need for the extra two variables.
                Set sCell = srg.Find( _
                    What:=dCombinedString, _
                    After:=srg.Cells(srg.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows) ' 'xlNext' and 'False' are default
                If sCell Is Nothing Then
                    dCell.Interior.Color = vbRed ' vbYellow, vbGreen
                End If
            Next dCell
        End If
    Next d
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
End Sub
```

**Optionally**

```vb
Sub MatchInsteadOfFind()
    ' Instead of 'Dim sCell As Range' use:
    Dim srIndex As Variant
    ' Instead of 'Set sCell...' use:
    srIndex = Application.Match(dCombinedString, srg, 0)
    ' Instead of 'If sCell...' use:
    If IsError(srIndex) Then
        dCell.Interior.Color = vbRed ' vbYellow, vbGreen
    End If
End Sub
```