Object variable or with block variable not set while writing macro

Getting the above error while executing a macros in the bold line:
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

**cell = targetSheet.Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row)**

'Tried to do number of fixes to get the cell as follows:
cell = targetSheet.Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row,8),Cells(ActiveCell.Row,8))

'but it is always executing the following code:
If cell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Cell not found.", vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If

which shows me that the particular cell cannot be referenced properly
Can anyone please help me here? Am new in VBA and have never written a macros.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872339/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-and-set-in-vba

You have to use Set keyword. Try-
Set cell = targetSheet.Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row)

