# Error setting return value of a VBA function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a brief foray in to VBA to automate some Excel workflow. I've got a function that creates a worksheet and returns it. I call it as follows:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = makeNewWorksheet(wb)
```

The function is:

```
Function makeNewWorksheet(wb) As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newWs As Worksheet

    wsName = "Bounced " & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = wsName Then
            Set newWs = ws
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If newWs Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add
        With ws
            .Name = wsName
            .Move after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        End With
    End If
    makeNewWorksheet = ws
End Function
```

When I try to assign the return value of the function on the last line (`makeNewWorksheet = ws`), I get an error:

```
Object variable or With block variable not set
```

None of the online docs I can find seem to apply in this situation. Everything is defined and the `ws` variable has a value.

Edit: Re. the accepted answer below. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba) an explanation of the `set` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
makeNewWorksheet = ws
```

should be:

```
set makeNewWorksheet = ws
```

Comment: Thanks, it's been a long time since I've used any BASIC variant. I just looked up the `set` keyword and linked to a relevant question above.