# How does a COM server marshal nullable in C# class library with different ComInterfaceType Enumerations?

Tags: c#, .net, vba, excel, com

I hear that `Nullable<T>` is a C# generic class and it does not work with COM - like any other generic class.

Well, in my C# class library I have:

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual),
Guid("2FCEF713-CD2E-4ACB-A9CE-E57E7F51E72E")]
public interface ICOMClass
{
    int? GetNullable();
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("57BBEC44-C6E6-4E14-989A-B6DB7CF6FBEB")]
public class COMClass : ICOMClass
{
    public int? GetNullable()
    {
        int? hello = null;
        return hello;
    }
}
```

*Surprisingly* that compiles and I am able to attach references to my `COMClass` library in VBE.

I know that:

- VBA does **not** list `.GetNullable()` in the list of members on Object Browser (even with *show hidden members* ticked)
- VBA does **not** list `.GetNullable()` in the intelli-sense drop down

but why:

```
Dim c as new COMClass
c.GetNullable
```

does **not** throw a rather expected `Object doesn't support this property or method`?

as opposed to:

```
c.NonExistingMethod
```

**Can anyone explain why?**

I am suspicious that it has something to do with [`ComInterfaceType` Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tz0x1301(v=vs.100).aspx) because

- both: `InterfaceIsDual` & `InterfaceIsIDispatch` act just like I described above

but:

- `InterfaceIsIUnknown` actually doesn't seem to marshal/*touch* the `GetNullable()` and the expected error is thrown...

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Look at this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66244/Marshaling-with-C-Chapter-Marshaling-Simple-Type
and do a search on `[Working with Nullable Arguments]` when you are on the page it will explain more in detail..

Comment: @DJKRAZE thanks a lot for the link however I didn't find an explanation to my question: why VBA allows a call to a method that in reality isn't visible anywhere on the COM library? I am the developer of that library so I know it exists and I found out VBA allows me to call `c.GetNullable()` - am I just asking why? Why isn't it completely hidden etc?

Comment: When you view the library in OLE View, is there any indication that the .tlb/.dll/whatever has GetNullable buried in the IDL?

Comment: @Mike I don't see it (`GetNullable()`) anywhere in OleView when viewing the type library...It clearly does not exist in the .tlb file but is somehow accessible directly from the .dll if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it compiles.  But you know you got trouble when you try to create a type library for the DLL:

```
C:\projects2\ClassLibrary38\bin\Debug>tlbexp ClassLibrary38.dll
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly to Type Library Converter 4.0.30319.33440
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

TlbExp : warning TX8013117D : Type library exporter warning processing 'ICOMClas
s.GetNullable(#0), ClassLibrary38'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a
 generic type instance in a signature. Generic code may not be exported to COM.
Assembly exported to 'C:\projects2\ClassLibrary38\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary38.tlb'
```

You can look at it by running OleView.exe on the type library.  This is what your interface looks like:

```
[
  odl,
  uuid(2FCEF713-CD2E-4ACB-A9CE-E57E7F51E72E),
  version(1.0),
  dual,
  oleautomation,
  custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "ICOMClass")

]
interface ICOMClass : IDispatch {
};
```

Nothing, nada, zippo.  Microsoft programmers sometimes are too friendly when they write diagnostic message.  It is not just "may not be", it is "will not be".

This is not going to work.  That it can find the method by late binding won't help, the return value cannot be interpreted properly, `Nullable<T>` is not [ComVisible].  As an alternative, consider that COM always had to notion of "nullability", strongly supported in VBA which depends on it a great deal.  Variants can store vtNull or vtEmpty to indicate that a value is not set.  It is *object* in C# code.

Comment: aha! Still don't quite understand how it actually **can** find the method since it does not exist in the *`.tlb`*. Is that true that the *`.tlb`* is only responsible for intelli-sense and Object Browser info and the *`.dll`* is being accessed directly? Like when you add references to a native .NET *`.dll`* and you can't see some methods in the Object Browser nor intelli-sense but you can still call *(and fail)* some members cause you know they exist due to familiarity with the API?

Comment: VBA uses late binding as a fallback, note how your interface implements IDispatch.  Bit of a flaw in the CLR, perhaps, could be intentional.

Comment: Additionally, I haven't seen the warning to start off with as VS didn't pop up the errors window for me and I didn't bother checking for warnings (yeah, I know my fault!!).