# Open a extern workbook and returning a worksheet does not work

Tags: vba, excel

My error has the number 1004:

```
Function getWorksheet(SheetNumber As Integer) As Worksheet

    Dim workbook As workbook
    Dim file As Variant

    file = ShowFileDialogAndFindFile

    Set workbook = Workbooks.Open(file, True, True)

    getWorksheet = workbook.Worksheets(SheetNumber)

End Function

Function ShowFileDialogAndFindFile() As Variant

    Dim fd As FileDialog

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

    With fd

        If .Show = -1 Then

            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems

                ShowFileDialog = vrtSelectedItem

            Next vrtSelectedItem
        Else
        End If
    End With
    Set fd = Nothing

End Function
```

I am invoking from another module:

```
Dim sheetExtern As Worksheet
sheetExtern = getWorksheet(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the keyword `Set` to do this. Basically:

**CANNOT WORK**:

```
Dim sheetExtern As Worksheet
sheetExtern = getWorksheet(1)
```

**SHOULD WORK** (assuming the rest of the function is ok):

```
Dim sheetExter As Worksheet
Set sheetExtern = getWorksheet(1)
```

Apart for native types (such as String, Integer, Double), when you want to set an object in VBA you need to use the keyword `Set` before.

OK: `a = 2` (native type Integer)
OK: `a = "hello"` (native type String)
KO: `a = New Collection` (Collection must be set, i.e. `Set a = New Collection`).

Worth answer to read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9924325/3111149) and background question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/349613/3111149)