# VBA: Argument not optional

Tags: vba, excel, collections

I'm trying to mess around with some collections in VBA for the first time.  I'm planning on using this collection to open multiple reports and run the same bit of code, which is why I wanted to get them into a collection.  (If there's a better way to do that, please let me know.)

---

My collection making Function (to return the collection?):

```
Function CollectReports() As Collection

    Dim reports As New Collection

    reports.Add Item:="plant1", Key:="0"
    reports.Add Item:="plant2", Key:="1"
    reports.Add Item:="plant3", Key:="2"
    reports.Add Item:="plant4", Key:="3"

    TestCollection (reports)

End Function
```

---

My collection testing Sub:

```
Sub TestCollection(reports As Collection)

    Dim x As Variant

    For Each x In reports
        MsgBox (x)
    Next

End Sub
```

I originally had the sub as `Sub TestCollection(ByRef reports)` which is what I've been using for other methods which require a Dim from another method.

---

**My issue** is that I get an `Argument not optional` error when I attempt to debug my `CollectReports()` function

---

If you're feeling really generous, here's the code block I'm planning on using this collection for - is a collection the best way to do this?

```
Sub VlookupMGCCode(ByRef reports)

Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim wRange As Range
Dim blankRange As Range
Dim x As Variant

lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set wRange = Range("$T$7:$T$" & lastrow) 'a single column to vlookup

CollectReports

For Each x in CollectReports 'deffinately an error here
    Set blankRange = wRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    blankRange.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-18],'[" & x & "]Sheet1'!C1:C31,31,FALSE)"

    With blankRange
        .FillDown
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, SkipBlanks:=False
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

---

I haven't tried running the `VlookupMGCCode()` Sub yet as the collection is needed, so I don't know what errors might come up, but I'm pretty confident that the way I'm trying to use the collection which `CollectReports` returns is wrong.

---

Thank you very much for your help and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15519085/4243498) for an explanation of when to use brackets.

You have a couple of issues:

1. This line needs to be changed:

   `TestCollection (reports)`

   To either

   `Call TestCollection (reports)`

   or

   `TestCollection reports`
2. Your `CollectReports` function is missing the line of code that assigns the collection. You need to add this line just before the end of the function:

   `Set  CollectReports = reports`

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer.  On the train of thought of `Set x = value`, could you explain why something like `Dim x As Integer` can be set with `x=1` while a range such as `Dim w As Range` needs `Set w as Range`?

Comment: Because one is a simple value and the other is a reference to an object. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9924325/4243498) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/349613/4243498)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error reporting is misleading, 
you are actually getting the error at TestCollection(Reports) you dont need brakcets when calling a sub. Please try removing this and feedback if it works

```
Function CollectReports() As Collection

    Dim reports As New Collection

    reports.Add Item:="plant1", Key:="0"
    reports.Add Item:="plant2", Key:="1"
    reports.Add Item:="plant3", Key:="2"
    reports.Add Item:="plant4", Key:="3"

    TestCollection reports

End Function
```

Comment: Yes, drop the parenthesis. Excel is really weird with how it treats parameters that are inside of parenthesis. Objects need to be passed outside of parenthesis or excel treats them differently. It's really odd. As said in another comment, using the Call keyword changes the way they are handled as well.

Comment: TestCollection (reports) expects that to be set to a value. something like tmp_var = TestCollection (reports) If I remember correctly

Comment: but TestCollection is a sub not function - no return value. why the assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Doing things slightly the wrong way round

```
Function CollectReports(reports As Collection) As Collection

    reports.Add Item:="plant1", Key:="0"
    reports.Add Item:="plant2", Key:="1"
    reports.Add Item:="plant3", Key:="2"
    reports.Add Item:="plant4", Key:="3"

End Function

Sub TestCollection()
    Dim reports As New Collection

    CollectReports reports

    Dim x As Variant

    For Each x In reports
        MsgBox (x)
    Next

End Sub
```

As for your other code I have not tested it all but

```
CollectReports

For Each x in CollectReports 'deffinately an error here
```

Change to

```
CollectReports reports

For Each x In reports 'deffinately an error here
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  However, it works better in my mind if I run the Function and then call a Test instead of the other way around.  @Krishna gave a solution which follows my train of thought more, but still, thank you :) -- this applies to the first post, not the edit :p