# Why must Set be used to hold objects?

Tags: vba

While working on my PowerPoint macro, I noticed the following:

To obtain the current, active slide:

```
Dim currSlide As Slide
Set currSlide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
```

To obtain a newly created Textbox:

```
Dim textbox As Shape
Set textbox = currSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(...)
```

I'm new to VBA, having worked with Java, C++ & C#. Why must `Set` be used above? Why does using `Slide` & `Shape` instead generate errors? In what way is VBA different in how variable declaration work in this respect?

Answer (score 2):

This is taken from [Byte Comb - Values and References in VBA](http://bytecomb.com/values-and-references-in-vba/)

> In VBA, the difference between value types and reference types is made explicit by requiring the keyword Set when assigning a reference. In addition, you will often see assigning a reference referred to as “binding”.

Byte Comb goes into great detail about the inter working of the VBA.  I highly recommend that any serious about programming using the VBA read through it.

In layman's terms:  Set is used so that the compiler knows that the programming wants to have a variable reference an Object type.  In this way, the compiler will know to throw an error when you are trying to assign a value to an object.

Another reason is that objects can have default values.

In this example I have a variable named `value` that is of a Variant type.  Variants can be of any type in the VBA.  Notice how the compiler knows that to assign the value of the Range when `value = Range("A1")` and to set a reference to the Range when the keyword `Set` is used in `Set value = Range("A1")`.

[image]

Comment: Also (and related) - objects in VBA can have default properties: for example `Range` has `Value` as its default property.  Without `Set`, something like `a = Range("A1")` would be ambiguous (do you mean make a equal to the Range itself, or to its Value?)

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks again.  I updated my answer.  I could have probably done a better job explaining it but I think stepping through the code example really emphasises out points.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481140/exposing-property-as-variant-in-net-for-interop/9924325#9924325

Comment: @TimWilliams Interesting and well written post. No wonder Hans Passant has 660k+ rep.

Comment: Thomas - what tool do you use to create these awesome gifs?

Comment: I use [ScreenToGif](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/).  It really rocks.