# Understanding Excel VBA Range Object

Tags: excel, vba

I have a following code that transfers a `range` into an `array`

```
Sub jaggedarray()
        Dim c(), i, j, k&
        For Each i In Range("B10:B39")
            For Each j In Split(i, ",")
                k = k + 1
                ReDim Preserve c(1 To k)
                c(k) = j
        Next j, i
        Range("O10").Resize(k) = Application.Transpose(c)
End Sub
```

Now I want to understand `For Each j In Split(i, ",")` I know `split` but how it operates on `range` object?
The `range` object defined as `i` what is its shape? I tried to figure it out using Locals windows in VBA editor but cannot get it.
This code also works for multi-range selection for instance `For Each i In Range("B10:B39, D10:D39, F10:F39")` this further complicates my understanding as the ranges are vertically stacked as single column as they should be.

Comment: `for each i in Range()` retrieves one cell at a time from that range. `for each j in Split()` separates values in that cell by a comma into individual values. The range shape is a rectangle from cell B10 to cell B39 - you can visualize it in Excel by opening a workbook and looking at the first sheet. For the multi-range selection it is still a series of rectangles or cubes, which again you can visualize in Excel.

Comment: It is equalient to `For Each j In Split(i.Value, ",")`.  `i.Value` is the content of the cell.

Comment: @KenWhite if my B10 to cell B39 `range` only has integer numbers or alphabets this `split` is doing nothing because there is no comma symbol. Am I correct ?

Comment: if there are no comma separated values, you only get one value back from Split(), which means you don't even need it or the loop that uses it - you can just access each cell's value directly.

Comment: To understand VBA you really need to get a grasp of *default properties* and how they work.  So `For Each i In Range("B10:B39")` is equivalent to `For Each i In Range("B10:B39").Cells` (so in this context `i` is a Range object representing a single cell) and as taller noted, the default property of a `Range` is its `Value` .

Comment: More on default properties (also explains the need for `Set` when assigning values to object-type variables) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481140/exposing-property-as-variant-in-net-for-interop/9924325#9924325

Answer (score 2):

### Range vs Array

**Random Tips**

- Learn about objects: workbook, worksheet, range...
- Learn about data structures: array, collection, dictionary
- Learn how to use `Debug.Print`.
- Use more variables and give them meaningful names and you will start to understand.
- Don't use shortcuts like `k&` or `Next j, i`.
- Declare the variables appropriately, and have as few variants as possible.
- The `Split` function produces an array of strings but a `For Each...Next` *control variable* (in the code `cell` and `SubString`) can only be an object or a variant so you will declare `cell` as a range (object) and `SubString` as a variant.
- Don't forget about the tips and links in your comments.

**The Code**

- Here's a rewrite to study and play with.

```vb
Sub RangeArrayComparison()
        
        Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
        Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("B10:B19")
        Debug.Print "The referenced range is """ & rg.Address(0, 0) _
            & """..." & vbLf & "... in sheet """ & ws.Name & """."
        
        Dim cell As Range, ArrResult() As Variant, SubStrings() As String
        Dim SubString As Variant, n As Long
        
        For Each cell In rg.Cells ' ws.Range("B10:B19").Cells
            Debug.Print "Cell """ & cell.Address(0, 0) & """ contains """ _
                & CStr(cell.Value) & """. " & IIf(Len(cell.Value) = 0, _
                "Nothing to split!", "Splitting:")
            
            SubStrings = Split(cell.Value, ",")
            
            For Each SubString In SubStrings ' Split(cell.Value, ",")
                
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve ArrResult(1 To n)
                ArrResult(n) = SubString
                
                Debug.Print n, SubString, cell.Address(0, 0)
            Next SubString
        
        Next cell
        
        ws.Range("O10").Resize(n).Value = Application.Transpose(ArrResult)
        
        Debug.Print "Retrieved " & n & " (sub)strings from " _
            & rg.Cells.Count & " cells."

End Sub
```

[image]

**Results in the Immediate Window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)**

```
The referenced range is "B10:B19"...
... in sheet "Sheet1".
Cell "B10" contains "a,b,c,d". Splitting:
 1            a             B10
 2            b             B10
 3            c             B10
 4            d             B10
Cell "B11" contains "". Nothing to split!
Cell "B12" contains "aa". Splitting:
 5            aa            B12
Cell "B13" contains "bb". Splitting:
 6            bb            B13
Cell "B14" contains "John,Peter". Splitting:
 7            John          B14
 8            Peter         B14
Cell "B15" contains "cc,dd,ee". Splitting:
 9            cc            B15
 10           dd            B15
 11           ee            B15
Cell "B16" contains "". Nothing to split!
Cell "B17" contains "15". Splitting:
 12           15            B17
Cell "B18" contains "124,7,33". Splitting:
 13           124           B18
 14           7             B18
 15           33            B18
Cell "B19" contains "". Nothing to split!
Retrieved 15 (sub)strings from 10 cells.
```

Comment: Extremely thanks

Comment: I have as question, you have declared x2 `variants`  but one has `()` for instance  ArrResult() & SubString

Comment: I wrote in the post why `SubString` is declared as a variant. Otherwise, I would have declared it as a string since it will always ever hold a string. `ArrResult()` means that this is a dynamically declared array i.e. it will be sized later in the code. In this case, it is necessary to use the parentheses because it wouldn't be possible to initially `ReDim Preserve` it. As you have learned from your code, a variant can hold any data type. But it is the one that consumes most of the memory. Use it when you have no choice or when it might hold different data types throughout the code..