# Invalid Use of Property?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working with an Access database and it has a form and VBA behind it. It has been quite a while since I dabbled in VBA and my google-fu is failing me right now so bear with me.

I created a simple class, and I am getting a compile error:

```
Dim oRecordSet As ADODB.RecordSet
Public Property Get RecordSet() As ADODB.RecordSet
    RecordSet = oRecordSet '' error here
End Property

Public Property Let RecordSet(ByVal val As ADODB.RecordSet)
    RecordSet = val
End Property
```

I have a couple other identical properties (different names/variables, obviously) that compile just fine; their types are `String` and `Integer`.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Also a side note, when I am coding the intellisense shows `ADODB.Recordset`, but on autoformat (carriage return, compile, etc) it changes it to `ADODB.RecordSet`. Need I be worried?

Comment: Objects are set using *Set*. All value types are OK with just =. So, Edmin is right about the cause of the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be:

```
Public Property Get RecordSet() As ADODB.RecordSet
    Set RecordSet = oRecordSet '' error here
End Property
```

Comment: Reading material for explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba

Comment: Ok cool. So why do the string/integer properties not need the `Set` and the RecordSet does?

Comment: string and integer are considered primitives (meaning they are passed by value) in VB6 so they do not need the Set keyword.