# Object variable or with block not set -

Tags: excel, vba

So, I have a worksheet, in which I want to search for a value of Range("M" & i) in Range("A:A"). However, when I try to run this code, it returns an error: "Run-Time Error '91': Object Variable or With block not set. When I click debug, it finds an error on

```
 SearchIn = Range("A:A")
```

I did google the internet and this site (found something), but I still can't solve the issue. Anyone got a clue?

```
Sub Find_Replace()

Dim i As Integer
Dim SearchIn As Range
Dim SearchedObject As Range
Dim FinalCell As Range
Dim SumCell As Range


i = 5
SearchIn = Range("A1:A740")
StartSearch = Range("A" & i)
FinalCell = Range("N" & i)

Do While i <= 740

SearchedObject = SearchIn.Find(What:="M" & i, After:=StartSearch, LookIn:=xlValues,          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If SearchedObject.Value = Range("M" & i).Value Then FinalCell = FinalCell.Value + SearchedObject.Offset(0, 5).Value

Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Related post which is **important to know** while working in VBA - [What does the keyword Set actually do in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/349613/465053).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When assigning a range, you have to use `SET`

```
Sub Find_Replace()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim SearchIn As Range
    Dim SearchedObject As Range
    Dim FinalCell As Range
    Dim SumCell As Range

    i = 5
    
    Set SearchIn = Range("A1:A740")
    Set StartSearch = Range("A" & i)
    Set FinalCell = Range("N" & i)

    Do While i <= 740

        Set SearchedObject = SearchIn.Find(What:="M" & i, After:=StartSearch, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
        If Not SearchedObject Is Nothing Then
            If SearchedObject.Value = Range("M" & i).Value Then _
            FinalCell.Value = FinalCell.Value + SearchedObject.Offset(0, 5).Value
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: Also it is advisable to use full path else the search will always happen in active sheet

For example

```
Set SearchIn = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A740")
```

Similarly for others.