# Object variable or With Block variable not set error when accessing members of BuildingBlockEntries collection

Tags: vba, object, iteration, ms-word

I am attemping to access members of a template's `BuildingBlockEntries` collection through a macro in Microsoft Word 2007. As it is a collection, I first thought a `For Each` loop would be the best way to to this:

```
 For Each bBlock In NormalTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries
        MessageBox.Show (bBlock.Name)
    Next bBlock
```

However this attempt through the error: `Object doesn't support property or method`.
So I tried this method which was suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/202d85a2-9583-4e55-b50e-9f98d773a319):

```
Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks   
Dim iBB As Integer
iBB = NormalTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries.Count()
Dim bb As Word.BuildingBlock
Dim i As Integer
Dim objCounter As Object

If iBB > 0 Then

  For i = 1 To iBB
    objCounter = i
    bb = NormalTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries.Item(objCounter)
    MessageBox.Show (bb.Name)
  Next

End If
```

However, this is resulting in the error shown in the title: `Object variable or With Block variable not set`.

I have tried just using an integer variable for the index, `i` specifically, but with now avail. How can I acheive the desired effect? What is wrong with my attempt?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your 2nd question the answer is that you need to use `Set`, as `bb` is an object:

```
Set bb = NormalTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries.Item(objCounter)
```

For more info on Set take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/349613/293078).

With your For/Next loop, it's not clear how you've declared `bBlock`. I guess it should be something like:

```
Dim bBlock as BuildingBlock
```

And perhaps the `For` line should reference `BuildingBlocks` instead of `BuildingBlockEntries`:

```
For Each bBlock In NormalTemplate.BuildingBlocks
```

I don't know for sure though, as I'm just looking at what pops up in Intellisense.

Comment: If I use `Set` keyword for bb, it exposes that a `Set` call is also required for objCounter, which still results in a type mismatch error when I call:
`Set bb = NormalTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries.Item(objCounter)`
Likely because `BuildingBlockEntries.Item()` is looking for an integer as an argument. However, if I remove `objCounter = i
` and change the argument of the call to:
`Set bb = NormalTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries.Item(objCounter)` I get the desired effect. Thanks for the info. Still unclear on how to get at the template with the basic Building Blocks, but that's a different question.