# Giving an array values in code

Tags: vba, excel

I created an array and gave tems 1 to 12 values. I did this to later loop through a part of code with each name. for some reason i get an error at my firs array fill line: "Object required". any ideas? And doe the rest of this code make sense too?

```
                Dim sArray() As String
                Dim row As Long
                Dim i As Long
                Dim arrTot() As Long
                Dim arrLate() As Long

          'Error here
                Set sArray(1) = "AAA CANADA INC."
                Set sArray(2) = "AEROTEK ULC"
                Set sArray(3) = "AKKA GROUPE AMERIQUE DU NORD INC."
                Set sArray(4) = "ALTITUDE AEROSPACE INC."
                Set sArray(5) = "ASSYSTEM CANADA"
                Set sArray(6) = "BERLETEX AERO DESIGN"
                Set sArray(7) = "MSB DESIGN INC."
                Set sArray(8) = "NORAMTEC CONSULTANTS INC."
                Set sArray(9) = "SATYAM COMPUTER SERVICES LTD."
                Set sArray(10) = "T.E.S. CONTRACT SERVICES INC."
                Set sArray(11) = "TATA CONSULTANCY SERVICES CANADA IN"
                Set sArray(12) = "TDM TECHNICAL SERVICES"

                Set vendor = Range("P2:P" & lr)
                row = 1
                For Each cell In invoicedates
                    For i = 1 To 12
                        If tbl1(row, 16) = sArray(i) Then
                            arrTot(i) = arrTot(i) + 1
                            duedate = cell.Value + 60
                            If Date > duedate Then
                                arrLate(i) = arrLate(i) + 1
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                    row = row + 1
                Next
```

Comment: As the error suggests `Set` is used for setting references to objects, not for assigning values. Remove the `Set`s. You must also dimension your array before using or get out of range errors.

Comment: you delcare the array but never set its size use the redim feature to resize your array. ReDim sArray(12).  Also note that unless you declare option base 1 in the module then all array index's start at 0

Comment: Define array as `Dim sArray(1 To 12) As String` and remove Set while assigning values to them.

Comment: this worked thank you. so what would set be for, like assigning a range to a range variable? is that an object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba

Comment: just fyi as you may find it convenient in the future, you can use the Array function to return a variant array based on the args, so e.g. rather than going x(1) = "a", x(2) = "b" etc, you can do x = Array("a","b")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: First you need to redim your array:

```
ReDim sArray(1 To 12)
```

Also, there is no 'Set' before assigning the values to an array.