# VBScript Opening folder to convert csv to xls

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript

Can anyone explain why this isn't working, its throwing an error saying:

Line: 14
Char: 1
Error: Object Required:'[string: "H:\VBS"]'
Code: 800A01A8

```
Const xlDelimited = 1
Const xlNormal = -4143 

Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim Excel
dim objShell
dim objFolder
Dim fileLocation

set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
set objFolder = objshell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select File Location", 1, "H:\")
set fileLocation = CStr(objFolder.self.path)

Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

folderDestination = InputBox("Enter Move to folder")
For Each f In fso.GetFolder(fileLocation).Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "csv" Then
        .Workbooks.Open
    .Sheets(1).Columns("A").TextToColumns .Range("A1"), xlDelimited,,,,,,,True,"|"
    .ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs .ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\1.xls", xlNormal
    .Quit
  End If
Next
```

Quite confused to say the least :S Once again any help is much appreciated!

Comment: this `set fileLocation = CStr(objFolder.self.path)` fails as you are trying to assign object to a string. Remove `set`

Comment: What's `folderDestination` doing there? It's never used. Also you're creating an Excel application twice, but you need only one. There's no need to quit Excel after processing one file. Recommended reading: [What does the keyword Set actually do in VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/349613/18771)

Comment: folderDestination is being used later once I pass this hurdle, also im not using VBA.

Comment: ...not to mention the three lines of code starting with `.Workbooks.Open`, which are obviously missing an enclosing `With` block. If I may give you the one piece of solid advice that you should frame and hang above the bed: **Don't copy random code off the internet. Especially code you don't understand.** Write every line yourself, *after* you are certain what it does.

Comment: VBScript and VBA are syntactically equivalent. Things true for VBA are true for VBS.

Answer (score 2):

"CStr(objFolder.self.path)" evaluates to a string, so you should not use `Set` (used for objects only) in the assigment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Const xlDelimited = 1

Const xlNormal = -4143 


Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


Dim Excel

dim objShell

dim objFolder

Dim fileLocation


set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")

set objFolder = objshell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select File Location", 1, "H:\")

set fileLocation = fso.GetFolder(objFolder.self.path)

Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

folderDestination = InputBox("Enter Move to folder")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder(fileLocation).Files

  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "csv" Then

        .Workbooks.Open

    .Sheets(1).Columns("A").TextToColumns .Range("A1"), xlDelimited,,,,,,,True,"|"

    .ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs .ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\1.xls", xlNormal

    .Quit

  End If

Next
```