# I set one range to another. When I delete the original range, the other is cleared. Why?

Tags: vba, excel

I set one range to another:

'Save row info

```
Set rRow = loSrc.ListRows(lListRowIndex).Range
```

When I delete the source, rRow is cleared.

```
'Delete row from table
loSrc.ListRows(lListRowIndex).Delete
```

Why does this happen? This wouldn't happen if I wrote:

```
iNumber = iSource + 1
iSource is nothing
```

And even more importantly, how can I stop this from happening, so that I can use rRow even after loSrc.ListRows(lListRowIndex).Delete has executed.

Comment: +1 This is a very interesting question, I noticed this once but didn't find an answer then.

Comment: Could you please add some more info about the code? It would be great to have at least the definition of the variables involved (such as `loSrc`, `iNumber`, `iSource`). Anyway, I suspect you are referencing the Range object (so when it's deleted, also the object `rRow` gets so).

Comment: P.S.: the set keyword creates a reference to the object (source [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/349636/3111149))

Comment: Is there any way to create a copy of the object instead of a reference to it? When I remove the Set keyword I get an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matteo NNZs comment help me understand this.

The Set keywork creates a reference to the object. When I delete the object, the reference is also affected.

By using

```
Dim vRow() as variant
```

instead of

```
rRow as range
```

I was able to write:

```
vRow = loSrc.ListRows(lListRowIndex).Range
loSrc.ListRows(lListRowIndex).Delete
```

and have vRow retain its values