# Excel vba Object variable or With block variable not set error

Tags: vba, variables, excel

I am coding in excel vba and get error 91 or a Object variable or With block variable not set error when i run my code and I am unsure as to why. I define and set my variables so I don't know what could cause the error. The relevant code is below

```
  Sub Button5_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim Month As Range
Dim Avg As Range
Dim Target As Range
Dim Incorrect As Range

Set Month = Range("J19")
Set Avg = Range("H19")
Set Incorrect = Range("A19")
Set Target = Range("M19")

'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 0 To 1000
If IsEmpty(Avg) Then

If Month.Find("jan") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("M19")
```

The error is on the If Month.Find("jan") <> "" then part of the code.

The full code is here:

```
Sub Button5_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim Month As Range
Dim Avg As Range
Dim Target As Range
Dim Incorrect As Range

Set Month = Range("J19")
Set Avg = Range("H19")
Set Incorrect = Range("A19")
Set Target = Range("M19")

'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 0 To 1000
If IsEmpty(Avg) Then

If Month.Find("jan") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("M19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("feb") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("O19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("mar") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("Q19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("apr") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("S19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("may") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("U19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("jun") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("W19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("jul") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("Y19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("aug") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("AA19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("sep") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("AC19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("oct") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("AE19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("nov") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("AG19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

Else
Set Target = Range("AI19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"

End If
End If

Else
If Month.Find("jan") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("N19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("feb") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("P19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("mar") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("R19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("apr") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("T19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("may") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("V19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("jun") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("X19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("jul") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("Z19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("aug") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("AB19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("sep") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("AD19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("oct") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("AF19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

ElseIf Month.Find("nov") <> "" Then
Set Target = Range("AH19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If

Else
Set Target = Range("AJ19")

If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Incorrect.Value = "X"
End If
End If
End If
Set Month = Month.Offset(1, 0)
Set Incorrect = Incorrect.Offset(1, 0)
Set Avg = Avg.Offset(1, 0)
Set Target = Target.Offset(1, 0)

Next i
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related post which is **important to know** while working in VBA - [What does the keyword Set actually do in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/349613/465053).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Range.Find` returns a `Range` so you need to evaluate it as an object:

```
If Not Month.Find("jan") Is Nothing Then
    Set Target = Range("M19")
End If
```

If you need to work with the returned `Range` you can use something like this:

```
Dim foundCell As Range
Set foundCell = Month.Find("jan")

If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    Set Target = Range("M19")
End If
```

The reference for `Range.Find` is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff839746%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: [Here some additional references.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff839746%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: It's good to note that objects need to be Set, while vars should not.

e.g. `Set worksheet = Worksheet` v.s. `x=4`