# How to use .Find in VBA to find a specific data type?

Tags: vba, excel

So I found this on the microsoft website (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) when I was trying to program something in VBA

expression .Find(What, After, LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat)
expression A variable that represents a Range object.

What: The data to search for. Can be a string or any Microsoft Excel data type.

And I wanted my code to find the first cell with the "Date" data type in a certain range, temp.

```
Dim temp As Range, next_date As Range
temp = Range("A63:A70")
Set next_date = temp.Find(Date)
Debug.Print (next_date)
```

But I keep getting the "Object variable not set" error, which I think means it was unable to find a date in the range. There is definitely a date in the range, but when I mouse over the "Date" I typed in the .Find(), I realise it shows the date today.

I think this code might be trying to look for today's date in the range. But I just want it to find a cell with a generic "Date" data type, is there any way to do this without specifying a specific date? Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for all your answers! I realised that I misread "Can be a string or any Microsoft Excel data type" -- I thought it meant that .Find could be used to find a specific data type, but I now realise it meant .Find can be used to find a certain string or number or date or any other data of other excel data types. I hope to avoid a loop because I actually am dealing with many hundreds of rows (but didn't specify that in the example) but so I'll probably use your answer, Jeeped! Also thank you Alex P and Dawid for the helpful input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not so much *'Is there a Date in A63:A70?'* but *'What else is in A63:A70?'*. Dates are not really a separate type of value. For *most* intents and purposes (more on this later), they are considered numbers. If all you want to to find the first Date-type in a range containing Dates, Text, Blanks but no other numbers then this should do.

```
    Dim temp As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set temp = Range("A63:A70").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    If Not temp Is Nothing Then
        Set temp = temp.Cells(1, 1) 'reset temp to the 1st date if there are more than one
        Debug.Print temp.Address
    Else
        Debug.Print "no date in range"
    End If
```

The reason I said *most* intents and purposes is because VBA does have an [IsDate Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278584.aspx). This likely looks at a) numeric nature of the value, b) difference between the Range.Value and Range.Value2 and c) the number format of the cell to determine whether a cell value is *42,149* or *25-May-2015*. However, the IsDate function can only examine a single cell at a time so a time-consuming loop through the cells is necessary.

```
    Dim temp As Range
    For Each temp In Range("A63:A70")
        If IsDate(temp) Then Exit For
    Next temp
    If Not temp Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print temp.Address
    Else
        Debug.Print "no date in range"
    End If
```

Your example was only 8 cells so a loop is not going to be overly detrimental to performance but it would certainly slow things down with a few thousand cells to individually examine.

Comment: Good point about loop performance - I thought about that in my answer i.e. if only small range then loop is fine but for large data sets it won't be as good.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you can use `Find()` to look for any value that is a date type. I think you would need to specify the actual date you are searching for instead. Example:

```
Set FoundCell = Range("A1:A10").Find (what:="7/18/1998")
```

An alternative option is a simple loop:

```
Sub FindNextDate()
    Dim val As Range

    For Each val In Range("A1:A10")
        If IsDate(val) Then
            Debug.Print "Date: " & val & " found at cell: " & val.Address
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next val
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`temp` is a object `Range`. You must use `set` -> [What does the keyword Set actually do in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba)

I think you cant find data type using `.Find()` but, you can try find format which indicates that we are dealing with date:

```
Sub tt()

Dim temp As Range, next_date As Range
Set temp = Range("A60:A70")

Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Set next_date = temp.Find("", SearchFormat:=True)

Debug.Print next_date
Debug.Print next_date.Address

End Sub
```