# How to use the FileSystemObject in VBA

Tags: vba, filesystemobject

So I'm quite new to VB and I'm just trying to create something that will open up a .txt file then read the first line and output it.
I've put my code below but when I run it I get the error

> Object variable or with block variable not set

because of the line

```
objTXT=objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\...",ForReading)
```

Any help, I feel like I'm missing something quite basic.

```
Private Sub Text_Reader()

    Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim objTXT As TextStream
    Dim str$

    Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject

    objTXT = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\...", ForReading)
    str = objTXT.ReadLine
    MsgBox (str)

End Sub
```

Comment: You're just missing a `Set` keyword in front of `objTXT = ...` [MSDN Reference to OpenTextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347(v=vs.60).aspx) and a [bit more here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/349613/2140173)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not use `Set` for opening. Try as follow:

```
Set objTXT = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\...", ForReading)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `FileSystemObject` to read textfile.
You can do it like that (without any external libraries):

```
Public Sub readTextFile(filepath As String)
    Dim intFile As Integer
    Dim text As String
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    intFile = VBA.FreeFile()

    Open filepath For Input As #intFile
    Line Input #intFile, text
    Close intFile

    Call MsgBox(text)

End Sub
```

Comment: That's an alternative but doesn't really answer the question asked.