# Error 462 in Excel VBA, how can I prevent it from happening?

Tags: excel, vba, object, ms-word, runtime-error

I made a post earlier about this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836289/using-excel-vba-to-open-word-template-populate-a-bookmark-then-save-with-a-fil) and now that I have the code working I am working out a bug. I can run the code once fine and dandy, but if I try to run the code a second time with a different value I get "runtime error 462: machine server doesn't exist or cannot be found"

I did some searching on [MS Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/178510) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba), which gave me an idea of what I'm supposed to be fixing, but I'm afraid I just don't understand what I need to do.

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
'
' Creates a new checksheet for the selected fixture data
'
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdApp.Visible = True

    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Copy

Documents.Add Template:="C:\Users\det10\Documents\Custom Office Templates" _
 & "\FSPC_Template3.dotx"
'
' Change this address to the proper storage location upon rollout
'
    With wdApp

        .Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Fixture_Number"
        .Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
        .Visible = True
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=ActiveCell.Text

    End With

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="C:\Users\det10\Documents\" & ActiveCell.Text & ".docx"

'
' Change the hyperlink address to the correct location upon rollout
'
End Sub
```

I think I'm supposed set Documents as an object or something like that, but I don't understand why and so far I have not been able to do anything with it.

Comment: `wdApp.Documents.Add Template:= ...`  also `.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2...`   Any time you're referring to something connected to Word you need to make sure you qualify it with `wdApp`

Comment: Looks like that solved the problem, thank you!

So by adding `wdApp` to the `Add Template` command that specifically tells the program to do that command in Word?

And then the extra `.` in front of `ActiveDocument` is basically just specifying that it's part of that `With` statement, right?

I'm really happy it works now, but I also want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly.