# VBA How to return from function

Tags: vba

I created a class module `Rect`:

```
Public top As Single

Public left As Single

Public bottom As Single

Public right As Single

Public Sub Class_Initialize()
    Me.top = 0
    Me.bottom = 0
    Me.left = 0
    Me.right = 0
End Sub
```

And a factory function to create `Rect` objects:

```
Private Function n() As Rect
    Dim r As New Rect
    n = r
End Function
```

When I call function `n()` I got runtime error '91'. I don't know what is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For object variables, you need to use `Set` to assign them:

```
Set n = r
```

See e.g. [What does the keyword Set actually do in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba)

Comment: The call to the rect object returned by the function **n()** would have to be Set as well. `Dim newer as object: Set newer = n()`. I must be missing something.