# Setting a collection property for a object in VBA

Tags: vba, class

I am having a class which has Collection as a property,

Bond Class

```
Private pBondiSIN As String
Private pBroker As Collection

''''''''''''''''''''''
' BondiSIN property
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get BondiSIN() As String
    BondiSIN = pBondiSIN
End Property
Public Property Let BondiSIN(Value As String)
    pBondiSIN = Value
End Property

''''''''''''''''''''''
' Broker property
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get Broker() As Collection
    Broker = pBroker
End Property
Public Property Let Broker(Value As Collection)
    pBroker = Value
End Property
```

And I call it this way:

```
Set tempBond = New Bond
tempBond.Broker = New Collection  => Gives me a error as Wrong number of Arguments or Invalid property assignment
```

Not sure how to solve this error. Need some help on this.

Comment: Use the `Set` keyword for complex objects like Collections

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get familiar with the [`Set` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/349624/2140173)

```
Public Property Set Broker(Value As Collection)
    Set pBroker = Value
End Property
```

and

```
Set tempBond.Broker = New Collection
```

Comment: when to use let and when to use set?

Comment: [have you already searched for an answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+set+let)