# VBA - returning a reference to a WorkBook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to call a function that returns a Workbook or reference to that workbook. However I'm unable to set the value 'wb' with the workbook returned from the function.

```
Public Sub TestScript()

    Dim wb As Workbook    
    wb = GetWorkBook()

End Sub


    Function GetWorkBook() As Workbook

    Dim db2 As Workbook
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    For Each xlWB In xlApp.Workbooks
        If xlWB.Name = "Test.XLSX" Then
            Set db2 = xlWB
        End If
    Next xlWB

    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlWB = Nothing

    GetWorkBook = db2


    End Function
```

Gives:

> Runtime Error 91:
>   Object Variable or With Block Variable not set

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to use the `set` statement two times:

```
Public Sub TestScript()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = GetWorkBook()

End Sub

Function GetWorkBook() As Workbook

Dim db2 As Workbook
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
For Each xlWB In xlApp.Workbooks
    If xlWB.Name = "Test.XLSX" Then
        Set db2 = xlWB
    End If
Next xlWB

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing

Set GetWorkBook = db2

End Function
```

Whenever you are assigning an object to a variable (reference it thereby) then you have to use the `set` statement (https://stackoverflow.com/a/349636/1153513).

Examples:

1. `Set rngYourRangeVariable = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C4")`
2. `Set shtSomeSheet = Thisworkbook.Worksheet("Sheet1")`
3. `Set conSomeADOconnection = New ADODB.Connection`

Comment: The key is using `Set` when setting the function name equal to the value to be returned: `Set GetWorkbook = db2`.  I just spent like 2 hours struggling with this, not understanding that the `Set` keyword could/should be used in this situation.  Thank you!