# "Object variable or With block variable not set" in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to calculate a column (in wsOut) of averages using VBA. The input is in another sheet (wsRefor).

I use the following code, where I use the worksheet function to calculate the average

```
Dim Avg As Double
Dim AvgRange As Range
Set Reformulering = ActiveSheet

For i = 1 To lastCol
    AvgRange = Range(wsRefor.Cells(1 + i, 4), wsRefor.Cells(1 + i, lastCol))
    wsOut.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(AvgRange)
Next
```

Yet, I get the mistake, from the second line inside of the for-loop:

"Object variable or With block variable not set"

I am not sure I understand the error from videos I have watched and other forum discussion, so I am hoping anyone can explain or potentially point of the mistake

Comment: Is the reference to `wsRefor` set OK, so that it points to a valid Worksheet object? If you run `MsgBox wsRefor.Name` first in the For-loop, do you get the same error? Btw, there is no If-statement in your example! :)

Comment: Hey @OlleSjögren. Yeah it should be. Also, thanks for pointing out that I wrote "if" and not "for". It is changed now :)

Comment: Related post which is **important to know** while working in VBA - [What does the keyword Set actually do in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/349613/465053).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you defined `Dim wsRefor As Worksheet`, and set it to the right Sheet, then modify your line:

```
AvgRange = Range(wsRefor.Cells(1 + i, 4), wsRefor.Cells(1 + i, lastCol))
```

to:

```
Set AvgRange = wsRefor.Range(Cells(1 + i, 4), Cells(1 + i, lastCol))
```

or, on the safe side:

```
With wsRefor
     Set AvgRange = .Range(.Cells(1 + i, 4), .Cells(1 + i, lastCol))
End With
```

**Edit 1**: full code which I've tested (also has error handling for the `Average` Function)

```
Option Explicit

Sub DynamicAvgRange()

Dim wsRefor             As Worksheet
Dim wsOut               As Worksheet
Dim Avg                 As Double
Dim AvgRange            As Range
Dim lastCol             As Long
Dim i                   As Long

Set wsRefor = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Refor")
Set wsOut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Out")

' just for simulating the tests
lastCol = 6

For i = 1 To lastCol
    With wsRefor
        Set AvgRange = .Range(.Cells(1 + i, 4), .Cells(1 + i, lastCol))
    End With
    If Not IsError(Application.Average(AvgRange)) Then
        wsOut.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = Application.Average(AvgRange)
    Else
        ' Average value returned an error (no values in the searched range)
        wsOut.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = "" ' put a blank value >> modify to your needs
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks so much. Increadble how much you gus help in here. When I run the code now, I get the error warning `Run time error '1004' Unable to get the Match propertyof the WorksheetFunction class`, but it still calculates and prints the averages. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @pApaAPPApapapa modify your line to  `wsOut.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = WorksheetFunction.Average(AvgRange)` , you don't need to use the `Application` before the `WorksheetFunction` , should work now

Comment: Done that. Same happens as before. It does calculate corretly, but still gives me the warning/error message.

Comment: @pApaAPPApapapa in you code you are running a loop `For i = 1 To lastCol` , and advancing the rows with this data ? you sure you don't have a Typo ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `Set` keyword when you are assigning an object rather than a value.

A `Range` is an object and so it needs to be `Set`

---

```
Set AvgRange = Range(wsRefor.Cells(1 + i, 4), wsRefor.Cells(1 + i, lastCol))
```

---

To see the difference, you can do this:

```
Dim test As Variant

Range("A1").Value = "some text"

test = Range("A1") '// test is now a string containing "some text"

Set test = Range("A1") '// test is now a range object

MsgBox test.Value '// Displays the value of the range object "some text"
```