# VBA range value from a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm trying to make a range value "paste" without using the copy/paste-function. I'm fairly new to VBA and don't understand why my code doesn't work. I'm sorry if this is a type of question which is already answered but I can't figure my problem out with other posts.

I'm able to select the range I want my values to copy from and paste too with

```
name_task = [code].select
name_task_2 = [code].select
```

But i can't write values to name_task_2 with

```
name_task_2 = name_task.value
```

This works, and for ME is what I've written somehow the same just more complex, but since it doesn't work it obviously isn't the same :D

```
sht2.Range("C2:D12") = sht1.Range("A8:B18").value
```

[Excel sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lTDT.png)

```
Sub Time_Estimate()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim name_task As Variant
Dim name_task_2 As Variant

Dim R_count As Double
Dim C_count As Double

Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = Sheet1 'Sheets("Tekla_2016")

name_task = sht1.Range("A8:B8", sht1.Range("A8").End(xlDown))
R_count = sht1.Range("A8:B8", sht1.Range("A8").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
'Debug.Print name_task.Rows.Count
'Debug.Print name_task.Columns.Count
Debug.Print R_count

Set sht2 = Sheet2 'Sheets("Timeforbruk_2016 - UFERDIG")

name_task_2 = sht2.Range("C2:D2", sht2.Range("C2:D2").Offset(R_count - 1, 0))

'name_task_2 = name_task.value 'Why doesn't this work???

'sht2.Range("C2:D12") = sht1.Range("A8:B18").value 'This works but it's not dynamic


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

EDIT:
This code now work as I want:

```
Sub Time_Estimate()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim name_task As Range
Dim name_task_2 As Range
Dim rng_sht1 As Range
Dim rng_sht2 As Range


Dim R_count As Double
Dim C_count As Double

Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = Sheet1 'Sheets("Tekla_2016")
Set sht2 = Sheet2 'Sheets("Timeforbruk_2016 - UFERDIG")

Set name_task = sht1.Range("A8:B8", sht1.Range("A8").End(xlDown))
R_count = sht1.Range("A8:B8", sht1.Range("A8").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Set name_task_2 = sht2.Range("C2:D2", sht2.Range("C2:D2").Offset(R_count - 1, 0))
name_task_2 = name_task.value

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work? The sub you posted or just the first to lines of code? Also important is the error message.

Comment: `name_task = [code].select` Doesn't work, but `name_task = [code]` should work, if `[code]` returns a range object. Just like in your other example: `sht2.Range("C2:D12") = sht1.Range("A8:B18").value` works, but `sht2.Range("C2:D12").Select = sht1.Range("A8:B18").value` will not work - it doesn't make sense.

Comment: If you are counting something like rows you don't need a `Double`. It's better to use an integer type. In VBA it is best to use `Long` (4 bytes) as `Integer` has only 2 bytes and thus has an upper limit of 32767

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
someRange.Select
```

selects the range `someRange` and returns the boolean value `True` (you usually don't notice that because you don't try to assign it to something). That means that after

```
name_task = [code].select
name_task_2 = [code].select
```

both `name_task` and `name_task_2` are booleans (`True`) and not ranges.

In the sub you posted you have another problem:

```
name_task = sht1.Range("A8:B8", sht1.Range("A8").End(xlDown))
```

since you didn't specify what `name_task` is (other than `Variant`, which basically means nothing), vba will use the range's `Value` as default property and `name_task` will be a variant array containing `sht1.Range("A8:B8", sht1.Range("A8").End(xlDown)).Value`. To assign a range *object* you need to use `Set`:

```
Set name_task = sht1.Range("A8:B8", sht1.Range("A8").End(xlDown))
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192490.aspx)/[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/349628/5959772):

> **Set Keyword**. In VBA, the **Set** keyword is necessary to distinguish between assignment of an object and assignment of the default property of the object. Since default properties are not supported in Visual Basic .NET, the **Set** keyword is not needed and is no longer supported.

This is actually a nice example why it is a good idea to use `Option Explicit` (or in your case to declare the variables properly). If you declare `Dim name_task As Range` VBA will tell you that something is wrong at the right line and troubleshooting becomes much easier.

Comment: fwiw, that's one of the better explanations I've read around here. [ALWAYS Use Option Explicit](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/3554/always-use-option-explicit#t=201609230832250056933)

Comment: Thanks for reply! The return key is not my friend on this forum.

I agree that variant is not a good idea and that's because of lack of knowledge, sorry. 

If I declare them as range I got it to work with set before both, name_task and
name_task_2


Can you explain a little further what the set-argument actually do?

Comment: I have Option Explicit on, but I thought declaring as variant would save me.

Comment: @Grohl I added an explanation of `Set` from MSDN. Declaring it as variant saved you from one error ;) There are some cases where you need a variant, such as working with arrays. Most of the time you are better off declaring variables as their actual type though.