# Storing chart titles in an array

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to store chart titles in a sheet into an array. I have the following code but it does not seem to work:

```
ReDim currentArray(1 To .ChartObjects.Count / 3) 
For i = 1 To .ChartObjects.Count Step 3
    .ChartObjects(i).chart.HasTitle = True
    title_name = .ChartObjects(i).chart.ChartTitle.Text
    If i = 1 Then
        Set currentArray(i) = title_name
    Else
        Set currentArray((i + 2) / 3) = title_name
    End If
Next
```

It gives me run-time error '424' message saying that object is required on line 6 where I try to store the title_name of the chart into currentArray. What other way is there to store just the chart names and not the charts themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See eg [What does the keyword Set actually do in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba)

The **Object Required** (424) error means that the right-side of the assignment statement does not return an object, when an object is expected/required by the left side of the assignment statement.

Basically you only use the `Set` keyword when working with Objects. Remove `Set` each time and it should work fine.