# Update an attribute in a record

Tags: ms-access, vba, updates, record

I am having a challenge with Access 2016.

I have created a button to update one attribute with another.
Example:
    QTY Value
    Quantity Request Value
    Remaining Stock Qty Value

I want to use a button to update the QTY value with the remaining stock qty value.

```
Private Sub Command67_Click()
Set QTY = QTY - QRAmount
Update Form_PartRequest
End Sub
```

But when I click the button nothing happens. What I'm missing?

Comment: `Set` is for objects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba

Answer (score 0):

If "attribute" means a field of the table the form is bound to, then:

```
Private Sub Command67_Click()

    Me!QTY.Value = Me!QTY.Value - Me!QRAmount.Value
    Me.Dirty = False

End Sub
```

Rename the controls to something meaningful.

Comment: Thank you, I assume that the me.! is the table example parts!.QTY

Comment: Yes, if the form is bound to that table.