# Determine if the VBE is open

Tags: vba, excel, vbe

I'm trying to develop an 'auto run' macro to determine if the VBE is open (not necessarily the window of focus, just open). If this is TRUE then ... take some action.

If this macro is connected to a CommandButton it works but I can't get it to function anywhere in the ThisWorkbook:

```
Sub CloseVBE()
    'use the MainWindow Property which represents
    ' the main window of the Visual Basic Editor - open the code window in VBE,
    ' but not the Project Explorer if it was closed previously:
    If Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True Then
        MsgBox ""
        'close VBE window:
        Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
    End If

End Sub
```

I was given the following FUNCTION to do the same but I can't get it to work either:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "User32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "User32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long

Private Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2

Function VBE_IsOpen() As Boolean

    Const appName       As String = "Visual Basic for Applications"

    Dim stringBuffer    As String
    Dim temphandle      As Long

    VBE_IsOpen = False

    temphandle = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString)
    Do While temphandle <> 0
        stringBuffer = String(GetWindowTextLength(temphandle) + 1, Chr$(0))
        GetWindowText temphandle, stringBuffer, Len(stringBuffer)
        stringBuffer = Left$(stringBuffer, Len(stringBuffer) - 1)
        If InStr(1, stringBuffer, appName) > 0 Then
            VBE_IsOpen = True
            CloseVBE
        End If
        temphandle = GetWindow(temphandle, GW_HWNDNEXT)
    Loop

End Function
```

**1/23/2018  Here is an update to the original question:**

I located the following code that performs EXACTLY as I was needing but when closing the workbook, the macro errors out on the line indicated:

```
Public Sub StopEventHook(lHook As Long)
    Dim LRet As Long
    Set lHook = 0'<<<------ When closing workbook, errors out on this line.
    If lHook = 0 Then Exit Sub
    LRet = UnhookWinEvent(lHook)    

    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

**Here is the entire code, paste this into a regular Module:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Const EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = &H3&
Private Const WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0

Private Declare Function SetWinEventHook Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal eventMin As Long, ByVal eventMax As Long, _
    ByVal hmodWinEventProc As Long, ByVal pfnWinEventProc As Long, ByVal idProcess As Long, _
    ByVal idThread As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, lpdwProcessId As Long) As Long

Private pRunningHandles As Collection

Public Function StartEventHook() As Long
  If pRunningHandles Is Nothing Then Set pRunningHandles = New Collection
  StartEventHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, 0&, AddressOf WinEventFunc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT)
  pRunningHandles.Add StartEventHook
End Function

Public Sub StopEventHook(lHook As Long)
  Dim LRet As Long
  On Error Resume Next
  Set lHook = 0  '<<<------ When closing workbook, errors out on this line.
    If lHook = 0 Then Exit Sub
    LRet = UnhookWinEvent(lHook)    

    Exit Sub
End Sub

Public Sub StartHook()
    StartEventHook
End Sub

Public Sub StopAllEventHooks()
  Dim vHook As Variant, lHook As Long
  For Each vHook In pRunningHandles
    lHook = vHook
    StopEventHook lHook
  Next vHook
End Sub

Public Function WinEventFunc(ByVal HookHandle As Long, ByVal LEvent As Long, _
                            ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal idObject As Long, ByVal idChild As Long, _
                            ByVal idEventThread As Long, ByVal dwmsEventTime As Long) As Long
  'This function is a callback passed to the win32 api
  'We CANNOT throw an error or break. Bad things will happen.
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim thePID As Long

  If LEvent = EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND Then
    GetWindowThreadProcessId hWnd, thePID
    If thePID = GetCurrentProcessId Then
      Application.OnTime Now, "Event_GotFocus"
    Else
      Application.OnTime Now, "Event_LostFocus"
    End If
  End If

  On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Sub Event_GotFocus()
    Sheet1.[A1] = "Got Focus"
End Sub

Public Sub Event_LostFocus()
    Sheet1.[A1] = "Nope"
End Sub
```

**Paste this into the ThisWorkbook :**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    StopAllEventHooks
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    StartHook
End Sub
```

Comment: Explain what "errors out" means, including the entire error message. And format your code - highlight the code lines, and press ctrl+k or click the `{}` button on the edit toolbar.

Comment: Just a side note but you could be killing the hook chain by not calling CallNextHookEx() in your WinProc.

Comment: The error message is :  Object required.     Please understand my knowledge of working with the API is less than nothing. These functions were located on the 'Net.

Comment: What I meant by "that performs EXACTLY as I was needing" is ... if the focus is taken off a worksheet it provides notification of such. I need for the API code to detect if the VBE has focus or is open and for the same notification to be given. From that .. instead of a notification I can replace that with a call to a macro to perform the subsequent needed action/s.

Comment: Interesting question. Out of curiosity, *why* do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just using the **ThisWorkBook module** with an `Workbook_Open` event?

**Code in `ThisWorkBook` code module**

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()         ' or...  Sub Workbook_Activate()
   ' checkIsVBEOpen
   If Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True Then
      MsgBox "VBE window is open", vbInformation
      ' do something
      ' ...
      ' close VBE window
        Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
    Else
      MsgBox "VBE window is NOT open"   ' do nothing else
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: T.M.   Thank you for your response. I have taken your suggestion and added a timing function to it, placing the code in a Routine Module. The timer checks and fires the action as required.     Again, THANK YOU to all who responded.

Comment: Do I need to mark this thread "SOLVED" or something similar ? If so ... how ?

Answer (score 2):

Good news: only two minor changes are required to get it to work fine on my system (Excel 2013 x86 on Win 8.1 x64):

- Comment out the offending line (!)
- Add the following declaration for [`UnhookWinEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373671(v=vs.85).aspx)at the top of the module:

  ```
  Private Declare Function UnhookWinEvent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hHook As Long)
  ```

`Set x=y` sets *object* variable `x` to reference object instance `y`.  As a result, it cannot be used for `Long`, `String`, or other non-object types.  That is why you get an `Object Required` error when that line runs.  Details of `Set` are in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/349613/2877364).

Separately, I'm not sure where you got the code from, but the error line would make the `StopEventHook` function a no-op if it worked:

```
Public Sub StopEventHook(lHook As Long)
    Dim LRet As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Set lHook = 0  '<<<- The error line --- throws away the input parameter!
    If lHook = 0 Then Exit Sub    ' ... then this always causes the Sub to exit.
    LRet = UnhookWinEvent(lHook)    

    Exit Sub ' note: don't need this; you can remove it if you want.
End Sub
```

If `lHook` did get set to 0, the next line would always cause the `Sub` to exit, so the hook would never be unloaded.

**Possible crash issue**

Sometimes Excel crashes when I close the workbook, but not always.  I actually don't think of that as a problem because I am used to hooks bringing down Office :) .  However, @RossBush's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48392964/determine-if-the-vbe-is-open/48462793#comment83816033_48392964) that "you could be killing the hook chain by not calling CallNextHookEx() in your WinProc" may be part of the issue.  If you run into that problem and can't figure out how to fix it, I would suggest asking a separate question.  There are certainly plenty of folks who have encountered the same!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm running Win 10 / Excel 2007. The code "tries to work" but there is hesitation and crashing here. I've decided to use a different approach incorporating a macro similar to the one listed below by T.M.