# UFT 14.00 how to use a property of function in different actions

Tags: vba, vbscript, hp-uft, uft14

I have this problem in UFT/QTP 14.00. I want use a property from a function to write a log file, but return this error when run the action.

[Error message: Object doesn't support property or method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogwiZ.png)

Here is my code:

```vb
Function Escrito
    'Function in VBS
    'Habilitamos la creacion y modificacion de archivos
        'Enable Create and update files
     Set fso=createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     set Stream = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\HCCMD\Documents\test.txt")
     Escrito = Stream
End Function
```

I want use `Escrito().write "Hola mundo"` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot `Set`.

```
Set Stream = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\HCCMD\Documents\test.txt")
Set Escrito = Stream
```

Or, easier

```
Set Escrito = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\HCCMD\Documents\test.txt")
```

Also see: [What does the keyword Set actually do in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/349613/18771) (applies to VBScript as well)

Comment: Thanks for your help Tomalak! God bless you!