# Run time error 9 Subscript out of range when activating a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to activate "Sheet1" of Workbook1 (Work.xlsm) as the image shows, I get a run time error. (There are no spelling mistakes).
[image]

It runs with no problems from another workbook (Book1.xlsx) for populating sheet (LS) data on to the UserForm Combo box and Text Boxes.

When I click on "ADD" button the userform data is populating on workbook (Book1.xlsx) sheet (LS) whereas I want it to populate on "Sheet1" of Workbook1 (Work.xlsm).

I am trying to call my main "Sheet1" sheet of Workbook1 (Work.xlsm) but get the error in this line.
[image]

From range A8 it should start populating (desired ouput in workbook1)
[image]

My code for combobox change and commandbutton(ADD):

```vb
Private Sub cboLs_Change()
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("LS")
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Val(Me.cboLs.Value) = ws.Cells(i, "A") Then
        MsgBox Me.cboLs.Value
        Me.txtProject = ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
    End If
Next i
End Sub


Private Sub cmdadd_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Work.xlsm")
    wb.Activate
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    'position cursor in the correct cell A2.
    ActiveSheet.Range("A8").Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = Empty
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'move down 1 row
        i = i + 1 'keep a count of the ID for later use
    Loop
    'Populate the new data values into the 'Data' worksheet.
    ActiveCell.Value = i 'Next ID number
    'Populate the new data values into the 'Data' worksheet.
    ws1.Range("A6").Value = e 'Next ID number
    ws1.Range("B6").Value = Me.txtname.Text 'set col B
    ws1.Range("C6").Value = Me.txtbook.Text 'set col C
    ws1.Range("D6").Value = Me.cboLs.Text
 End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("LS")
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Me.cboLs.AddItem ws.Cells(i, "A").Value
    Next i
 End Sub
```

Comment: are you sure you need to be saying "Set"? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba

Comment: In which line you mean? I used "Set" to read the worksheet as an object.

Comment: My main issue is in my commandbutton code the new workbook with "Sheet1" is not getting activated. My userform data is tranferring to other workbook but not the workbook which I want to be.

Comment: You have worksheet references - use those instead of `Activate` and `Select`.

Comment: i = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row  : you mean this way?

Comment: How to activate my second workbook for the commanbutton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple:

`Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")` throws a `Subscript out of Range` error, because there is **no sheet with the name "Sheet1"** contained in the file "C:\Users\Desktop\Work.xlsm"

You are referencing by the `Name` of the WorkSheet object, this is what is displayed on the little tab. The Object might very well be "Sheet1" in your object explorer in VBA:

- In that case you can use `Set ws1 = wb.Sheet1`
- If you wish to use the name, check the tab in the Excel GUI, and use `Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Whatever is displayed on the little tab at the bottom of your screen")`

For some examples on how to reference sheets, read [this](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-guide-to-referencing-excel-worksheet-tabs)