# Converting values in from two Comboboxes to build a table

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-word, integer

First, thank you in advance...everyone here has been incredible

So what I am trying to do is use two comboboxes (cb_RNNumberPayments and cb_CountCohorts) to insert a table into my document at a bookmark "FeeTable".  Also I am trying to make sure to format the table correctly (but that is probably a future struggle).  Now because the table has a header (so need to have it oRow+1) and has two additional columns (oCol +2) and based on what I have read, comboxes do not read as integers, I am running into a load of issues.  I can get it to work if I just set oRow =4 and oCol =4 but since each the column and row numbers are different everytime, I want to write it to be based off the comboboxes...make senser?  I am also looking to insert specific text into the column headers (Col1 Nursing Program Class, Col2 First Term, Col3 Second Term, Col4-6 are dependent on if the column exist based on the combobox cb_RNNumberPayments and the last col should be Total Fee

```
Sub FeeTable()
    Dim oRng As Word.Range, oTbl As Word.Table
    Dim RNPayment As Integer
    Dim nCohort As Integer
    Dim oRow As Integer
    Dim oCol As Integer

    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range.Bookmarks("FeeTable").Range
    Set oCol = cb_RNNumberPayments.Value + 2
    Set oRow = cb_CountCohorts.Value + 1
    Set oTbl = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=oRng, NumRows:=oRow, _
                                         NumColumns:=oCol)
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "FeeTable", oTbl.Range
    oTbl.Rows.SetLeftIndent LeftIndent:=InchesToPoints(0.3), _
                            RulerStyle:=wdAdjustSameWidth
    With oTbl
        .Borders.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .Borders.InsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth025pt
        .Borders.InsideColor = wdColorBlack

        .Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .Borders.OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth025pt
        .Borders.OutsideColor = wdColorBlack
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: You only use `Set` for object-type variables.  Try (eg) `oCol = CInt(RNPayment.Value) + 2`  "I am running into a load of issues"  - would be useful to be more explicit about exactly what those issues are: do you get an error message, and if so what is the error and on which line?

Comment: I am getting Compile error: object required.  I did change it  Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range.Bookmarks("FeeTable").Range
    Set oCol = CInt(cb_RNNumberPayments.Value) + 2
    Set oRow = CInt(cb_CountCohorts.Value) + 1
    Set oTbl = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=oRng, NumRows:=oRow, NumColumns:=oCol)

Comment: Ranges/Tables/etc are objects and require `Set` in assignments. `Integer/string/Long/etc` are not object types and so you don't use `Set` for those.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!!!! worked like a charm