# VBA Worksheet Variable

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to use Worksheet variables as I'd expect them to.

```
Function Test()
    Test = Application.ThisCell.Worksheet.Range("A1").Value
End Function
```

The above function works as expected, returning the value of cell "A1" in the same worksheet as the cell the function was called from.

```
Function Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    ws = Application.ThisCell.Worksheet
    Test = ws.Range("A1").Value
End Function
```

This one should be functionally the same, but breaks and returns #VALUE! instead.

I can make do with the former, but, in formulae that require it several times, I'd rather only get the worksheet location once.

Any input on why my second example doesn't work and how to fix my issue would be welcome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/creating-object-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `Worksheet`Variables you must use `Set` .

In your case `Set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("NameOfTheSheet")`

Thought... you are trying to set the worksheet using some variable, i would Hardcode the name or use a loop to get it.

Comment: Thanks, this works.

Other variables work fine without using Set, so I didn't expect that I would need it.

Comment: **Object** variables (i.e. those that aren't simple data types) require `Set`