# Set a Minimum Value for the X-Axis

Tags: excel, vba, charts, axis

Currently I am manually inputting the date of a project as an excel serial number into the Axis options of my chart (Bounds => Minimum).

I am trying to place code in the worksheet to make it update this value automatically upon changing the start date.

I've spent hours on the internet trying to find the code that will work, and piecing together bits of code to do the job, but I keep getting run errors

At the moment I have got to this point with the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cht As Chart
Dim xmin As Integer

    Set xmin = Sheets("Planning").Range("O37").Value

    Set cht = Worksheets("Planning").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart

    cht.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = xmin

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `Set xmin =` should be `xmin =` You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba)

Comment: I think the `xlCategory`-Axis (usually the x-axis) has not the option to  set bounds,  units and scale. Do you mean the `xlValue`-axis?

Comment: From what I was reading the xlcategory referred to the X-axis, so just thought that was the format I had to use. I guess I just need what ever is going to let me set the minimum x-axis value based on a cell value.

Comment: You can set the xlCategory axis minimum in a scatter chart, or in another type of chart (line, area, column) if the axis has a date scale (xlTimeScale in VBA).

Comment: I'm using a horizontal bar chart as a gantt chart....

Comment: Ah-HA! In a horizontal bar chart, the X axis, the independent variable, is vertical, and the Y axis, the dependent variable) is horizontal. So you need to change the Y axis minimum, or `cht.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale`.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks - I have changed it to (xlValue), however, when I tun tyhe code I get a run-time error '6', stating overflow, and highlights the line of code that says
```
xmin = Sheets("Planning").Range("O37").Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - so I managed to get the following code to work as I wanted

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim objCht As ChartObject
   For Each objCht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
      With objCht.Chart
         ' Value (Y) Axis
         With .Axes(xlValue)
            .MinimumScale = Sheets("Planning").Range("E3").Value
         End With
      End With
   Next objCht

End Sub
```

Thanks everyone for the help and tips!