# VBA how to change a range variable using something like offset

Tags: excel, vba

I'd think that the following code should produce a diagonal of numbers, and I am wondering why this code doesn't work as intended:

```
Sub RangeExample()

Dim a As Range

Set a = Sheets(1).Range("a1")

a.Value = 0

Dim i As Integer


    For i = 1 To 100

        a = a.Offset(1, 1)
        a.Value = i

    Next i

End Sub
```

I understand there are many ways of producing a diagonal of numbers,  I'm not asking how to do that.
What I'm asking is how I would change my range variable a to become a different range, and do that iteratively.  It seems to me that as `a.offset(1,1)` returns a range object that's one over and one down, I should be able to reassign a as this new range, assign a value, and move on.

Comment: You're missing `Set`: `Set a = a.Offset(1, 1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current issue is that you're missing a `Set`:

```
Set a = a.Offset(1, 1)
```

Note that you could also just use `i` and not re`Set`:

```
a.Offset(i, i).Value = i
```

Another option is to use `Cells`, e.g.

```
Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, i + 1).Value = i
```

There's more than one way to skin a cat - pick whatever is easiest and most intuitive to future you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, I didn't know `set` was required in this case.  The specific answer I was looking for I have now found at:

[What does the keyword Set actually do in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba)

Specifically, the following answer by LeppyR64. "Set is used for setting object references, as opposed to assigning a value."

I didn't know that equality alone only impacted the value of the range object `a`.  To actually change the range `a` was referencing, I needed `set` because `a` is supposed to refer to a new range object.

Answer (score 0):

the issue has already been addressed by @BigBen

but you could avoid re-setting the range at every iteration by means of `With...End With` block

```
Option Explicit

Sub RangeExample()
    Dim i As Long

    With Sheets(1).Range("a1") ' reference topleftmost cell
        .Value = 0 ' write referenced cell value
        For i = 1 To 100
            .Offset(i, i).Value = i 'write referenced cell current offset value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```