# “Compile error: Object Required” in Goalseek function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate the Goalseek function.

```
Sub Goalseek()
Dim rw As Integer
Dim cl As Integer

Set rw = ActiveCell.Row
cl = ActiveCell.Column
To_value = Cells(rw, cl - 25).Value

Cells(rw, cl + 6).Goalseek Goal:=To_value, ChangingCell:=Cells(rw, cl)

End Sub
```

And the

> Compile error: Object Required

shows up.

Comment: Remove the `Set` on the `rw =` line.

Comment: As the error says, you need an object to use the `Set` keyword. `Integer` is not an object, it's a value type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349613/what-does-the-keyword-set-actually-do-in-vba

Comment: Side note: you probably want to `Dim` the variables as `Long`. Excel can handle more rows than `Integer` can count